# Using Angular2, how to redirect to previous url before login redirect

Tags: redirect, angular, angular2-routing

Using Angular2 to create a single page app, I'm intercepting unauthenticated user access to non-public routes in a custom `RouterOutlet` and redirecting them to a login view.  After a successful login, I want to redirect the user to their originally requested view, rather than the default view.

I've noticed that `Router` has a `renavigate()` function that navigates to the last successful route BUT the last successful route was `/auth/login` and not the originally requested url.

*Basically : How can I access, or determine the previously requested url?*

I don't really want to resort to passing query string parameters around, unless I really have to.  Ideally it would be nice to have access to `history` collection as part of the `Router` component, similar to `backbone.history`!

Comment: What about `location.back()`?

Comment: This answer may useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59008239/7059557

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Use Auth Guards (implements [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html)) to prevent unauthenticated users. See [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) with examples and [this blog](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial).
2. Use [RouterStateSnapshot](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterStateSnapshot-interface.html) in the auth guard to capture the requested URL.

   ```
   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) 
   {
       // keep the attempted URL for redirecting
       this._loginService.redirectUrl = state.url;
   }
   ```
3. Redirect to that URL on successful authentication with using [Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html) (e.g. in the `login.component.ts`). E.g. `this._router.navigateByUrl(redirectUrl);`

P.S. Suggestions of @MichaelOryl and @Vitali would work, but my way is more aligned with Angular2 final release.

Comment: Note that `state.url` doesn't actually contain the entire url that the user entered - it contains the url that points to the state being guarded.  So (1) this method won't redirect to children of the guarded state and (2) any auxiliary routes will be removed from the url.

Comment: @JonathanMiles The explanation seems pretty straigh forward, but I'm affraid I do not follow. I do not understand how to create the `_loginServie`.

Comment: @AaronC, creating a login service is out of the question's scope. Just to point you to the right direction, see the [official tutorial on services](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) and a a couple of examples: [from Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-authentication/) and [from Jason Watmore](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial)

Comment: (i) first thx to Alex Klaus for a perfectly working solution; (ii) I guess Aaron C was struggling at that time to find out whether he needed to use a particular library/service or not. The _loginService refers to any kind of login- or authenticationservice you have designed/you're using and have injected in the constructor of auth.guard.ts. As a newbie and untalented developer, that's how I understood the remark. Take care, good luck & thx.

Answer (score 8):

You might find what you need in the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Location-class.html) for the `Location` class.  The `back()` function could possibly do it for you.

Another approach would be to subscribe to the `popstate` events in `Location`, instead.  [MDN has docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) talking about the values you could expect to receive.

```
class MyCLass {
  constructor(private location: Location) {
    location.subscribe((val) => {
        // do something with the state that's passed in
    })
  }
}
```

Otherwise you might want a service that tracks the changes in the Router so that you can access them.

```
class MyTrackingService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.subscribe((val) => {
        // store the routes here so that you can peel them off as needed?
    })
  }
}
```

In this case I'm accessing the `Router` object and subscribing to any changes so that I could track them.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's one option to consider.  Ideally I'm looking for the Angular2 best practice, although I also appreciate it's still BETA and likely to change.  I've noticed that Location > PlatformLocation contains a history collection but there appears to be no valid method of interacting with it from the Router; which is my preferred method and Angular2 recommended method of navigating the app.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. Inject it into your main App component's constructor having registered it in the bootstrap method.
The first `val` on page load should be the original URL.
I am unsubscribing right after to be efficient since I don't (perhaps, yet) want to listen to subsequent router events in this service.
Inject the service into other places where originalUrl is needed.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Injectable()
export class UrlTrackingService {

  public originalUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {
    let subscription: Subscription = this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      this.originalUrl = val.url;
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: In your `bootstrap` method add this service, so you can use it in other components or services.
`bootstrap(AppComponent, [ ..., OriginalUrlService, ... ]).catch(err => console.error(err)); `
Then inject this service just like you would any other service (e.g. http) and use the `originalUrl` property to perform the router redirect as needed. In your own component or service add: `
  constructor(
    private ous: OriginalUrlService,
    private router: Router
  ) { ... }

  private someMethod(): void {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(this.ous.originalUrl);
  }
`

Answer (score 4):

**Updated Example Using Angular 2.2.1**

Auth Guard that passes original URL to login component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login', { returnUrl: state.url }]);
        return false;
    }
}

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { AlertService, AuthenticationService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
```

Login Component that redirects to the previous / original URL after login:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;
    returnUrl: string;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertService: AlertService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status
        this.authenticationService.logout();

        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.params['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    // login successful so redirect to return url
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    // login failed so display error
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
    }
}
```

For more details and working demo you can check out [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/08/angular-2-redirect-to-previous-url-after-login-with-auth-guard)