# How to get current route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The current docs only talk about getting route params, not the actual route segments.

For example, if i want to find the parent of current route, how is that possible?

Comment: `window.location.pathname`

Comment: @dchacke the problem with `window.location` is that if in the future, they want to implement server-side rendering, they will face some difficulties since `window` does not exist on the Node.js server, but they need to use the Angular standard methods to access the route and they'll be fine both on server and browser.

Answer (score 853, accepted):

The new V3 router has a url property.

```
this.router.url === '/login'
```

Comment: I use this code and i am getting this url in string variable but when i try to print in console .log it is not printing                                                                                     this.fullUrl =  this.router.url  
console.log(this.fullUrl);   // not printing

Comment: Look at using the new router active feature <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>

Comment: this works with the current [angular2-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed) (which is currently on angular 2.2.1).

Comment: This isn't really a great solution because if you want to see if the current route is the root `/` if there is a query string you'll end up with `/?q=something` which would break this.

Comment: This is incredibly useful for creating persistent buttons that route somewhere, and return home when clicked again. No need to create a service to follow the state if the router does it for you!

Comment: this is useless when you are navigating with Hash strategy, the url is always "/"

Comment: @NinjaCoding I am using Hash strategy and I am getting just "/". How can i get route url with Hash ?

Comment: @Murtuza here is a solution: `this.router.events.filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(event => {
            console.log('this is what your looking for ', event.url);
        });` . Make sure you import `import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
`

Comment: now is 2019 - I use hash strategy - and it works - return right url e.g. `"/login"`

Comment: @Murtuza 's comment/answer is correct, just remember that now to be able to use filter you have to wrap it in pipe so it will be:
`this.router.events.pipe( filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd) ).subscribe(event => { console.log('this is what your looking for ', event.url); });` and you have to import pipe too.

Comment: @Murtuza pointed me in the right direction. However, not need to filter, just listen for NavigationEnd  ```this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      event instanceof NavigationEnd ? console.log(event): null
    })```

Comment: This does not solve issue. Question was about route segments, not full url. For example you need to store last url with query parameters and restore the url, then you would need to extract query parameters from the string, then store the url. That solution is way too complex. There are other options to solve this

Comment: Just piggybacking on Matthew Pitts' answer, I used this code to perform some actions whenever the route changed:
---
`this.router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEnd | null) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(event.url);
  }
});`

Comment: This is how it worked for me:
`this.router.events.pipe(filter((event: NavigationEnd) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(event => {  console.log('this is what your looking for ', event.url); });`
`

Comment: Is there not official proper way from Angular to returns the route as level array. I could process the url by my self. For example split by `'/'` etc. But I can't believe that Angular has no functions for that. Use case: Implement a method like `isDashboard` which checks the first level route and is also true on routes like: `dashboard/one`, `dashboard/two/three`, etc.  Yes I could use something like `router.url.startsWith('/dashboard/')`, but is there really not official better way from Angular? ...

Comment: There is also the need to subscribe to it so that we can reload the component correctly

Comment: Some people say this does not work for hash strategy, but for me it does work. I am getting the url and not just the "/". Has things changed in the last years? I am using Angular 14.

Comment: If you want to always listen to the route and also get the first loaded route, you can use this code.

`private router = inject(Router);
  currentRoute = signal<string>('');

this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
      this.currentRoute.set(event?.routerEvent?.url); // this is the current route you need
    }); 
`

Answer (score 285):

Angular RC4:

You can import `Router` from `@angular/router`

Then inject it:

```
constructor(private router: Router ) {

}
```

Then call it's URL parameter:

```
console.log(this.router.url); //  /routename
```

Comment: The extra clarity about how to import the router itself is very helpful. Could you clarify if it would be different if you were using a custom Router?

Comment: That would certainly depend on the 'custom-ness' of the custom Router.  (sorry this wasn't a particularly helpful comment -- if you have a specific question, I'd suggest making a new question and referencing this answer)

Comment: I used this solution, but I always get this " / ". Does anyone know why?

Comment: Angular Dependency Injection relies on the TypeScript sugar syntax, so when you declare private _router: Router in the constructor signature, a property _router is automatically created in the current class instance with the Router injected. This statement this.router = _router; is just an overhead to me, as you'd have two reference to the same object instance (in that case, the Router).

Comment: @Marcio M. It might be because the router has not actually reached that state, even though the URL shows different. For example, if your look at the router.url in a guard service. location.path() as mentioned in the answers will give you the url, no matter what the router state is.

Comment: @MarcioM.See Ninja Coding's answer above: "this is useless when you are navigating with Hash strategy, the url is always "/"". What strategy are you using?

Comment: I'm not using the Hash strategy, and I always get "/" as the result....

Answer (score 74):

Inject `Location` to your component and read `location.path();`
<strike>You need to add `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` somewhere so Angular can resolve `Location`.</strike> You need to add `import: [RouterModule]` to the module.

**Update**

In the V3 (RC.3) router you can inject `ActivatedRoute` and access more details using its `snapshot` property.

```ts
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
  console.log(route);
}
```

or

```ts
constructor(private router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(...);
}
```

See also [Angular 2 router event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912932/angular-2-router-event-listener/35912966#35912966)

Comment: that gives me the 'url' path. how do i find the 'route names' so i can pass them in an array on to the `navigate` method along with the (appended) name of child route i want to navigate to.

Comment: I see. I also don't find this satisfactory. I haven't tried it myself but maybe the `MyTrackingService` explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34548656/217408 would allow to access these values.

Comment: Route names are gone now.

Comment: @GunterZochbauer is there a way to get the _requested_ route _before_ it's activated?  For example, if I want to store the _requested_ route inside of a `canActivate()` method, so that I can redirect to a "login" page, and then redirect _back_ to the original route after the user authenticates?

Comment: Can't you do that with a canActivate guard?

Comment: @Yevgeny Refer http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/08/angular-2-redirect-to-previous-url-after-login-with-auth-guard for your requirement

Comment: isn't listening to router events too expensive?

Comment: No idea why you think listening to these events could be expensive. Router event are quite infrequent and all this listening does is storing the callback in a list to be called when a router event happens. I'd say if you care about performance you're better off checking for unnecessary server requests and DOM re-render.

Comment: No idea why you think listening to these events could be expensive. Router event are quite infrequent and all this listening does is storing the callback in a list to be called when a router event happens. I'd say if you care about performance you're better off checking for unnecessary server requests and DOM re-render.

Answer (score 74):

Use this

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .subscribe(event => {
            console.log(event);
        });
}
```

And in `main.ts` import

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
```

**EDIT**

Modern way

```
import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';

router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
)
    .subscribe(event => {
        console.log(event);
    });
```

Comment: Is this really the recommended way to do something as simple as checking where the current URL is pointing? I'm not arguing against you on this one. However, I noticed that the routing thing is a source of many changes, updates, confusions etc. I was kind of expecting that *ActivatedRoute* would be used primarily for this, not *Router*. Am I missing the complexity of the issue, perhaps?

Comment: I'm referring to [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) in the official docs.

Comment: No need for any at least here, the router exports the  "RouterEvent" type that is extended by the other router events - https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent

Comment: @chrismarx fixed

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Actually, if you're dealing with nested modules which contain their own routes, then yes. In fact, using nested modules and routers (which is what the Angular Team even recommends) this is the *only* way to get the actual URL of the current route, all other methods will simply return `/`.

Comment: this works fine.  but when i start the app, first time at that time no event is fired. this works when the route change

Comment: @SunilGarg You could use the `startsWith` rxjs operator

`startWith(this.router.url),`

Comment: For correct typing `filter((event): event is NavigationStart => event instanceof NavigationStart),`

Answer (score 53):

For those who are still looking for this. On Angular 2.x there are a few ways of doing it.

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){

   // string path from root to current route. i.e /Root/CurrentRoute
   router.url 

    // just the fragment of the current route. i.e. CurrentRoute
   activatedRoute.url.value[0].path

    // same as above with urlSegment[]
   activatedRoute.url.subscribe((url: urlSegment[])=> console.log(url[0].path))

   // same as above
   activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path

   // the url fragment from the parent route i.e. Root
   // since the parent is an ActivatedRoute object, you can get the same using 
   activatedRoute.parent.url.value[0].path
}
```

References:

1. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html
2. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html
3. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 44):

**for new router >= RC.3**

Best and a simple way to do this is!

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(router: Router) { 
      router.events.subscribe((url:any) => console.log(url));
      console.log(router.url);  // to print only path eg:"/login"
}
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from lowcrawler's?

Comment: @not2savvy had given one more way to find out the same through router event listener, which helped some of the people to find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 33):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(router: Router) { 
      console.log(router.routerState.snapshot.url);
}
```

Comment: Hallelujah! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

**To get the route segments:**

```
import { ActivatedRoute, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';

constructor( route: ActivatedRoute) {}

getRoutes() { const segments: UrlSegment[] = this.route.snapshot.url; }
```

Answer (score 21):

To reliably get the full current route you can use this

```
this.router.events.subscribe(
  (event: any) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      console.log('this.router.url', this.router.url);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, because if you change routes, this will catch it.

Answer (score 21):

An easier way if you can't access router.url (for instance if you used skipLocationChange) you can use the following :

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';    
constructor(private readonly location: Location) {}
    
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.location.path());
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can try with

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';    

constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url)  // array of states
console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path) }
```

Alternative ways

```
router.location.path();   this works only in browser console.
```

`window.location.pathname`  which gives the path name.

Comment: update: activatedRoute.snapshot.url is an Observable now and you have to subscripe to it.

Answer (score 14):

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private router: Router) {
  // Detect current route
  router.events.subscribe(val => {
    if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      console.log(val.url);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It gave undefined value sometimes

Answer (score 13):

The native `window` object works fine as well

```
console.log('URL:' + window.location.href);
console.log('Path:' + window.location.pathname);
console.log('Host:' + window.location.host);
console.log('Hostname:' + window.location.hostname);
console.log('Origin:' + window.location.origin);
console.log('Port:' + window.location.port);
console.log('Search String:' + window.location.search);
```

NOTE: DO NOT USE THIS IN SERVER SIDE RENDERING

Comment: Be careful if you are using server side rendering, this will break.

Answer (score 8):

to get current router in angular 8 just do this

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
```

then inject it in constructor like

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

if you want get current route then use this `route.url`

if you have multiply name route like `/home/pages/list` and you wanna access individual then you can access each of like this `route.url.value[0].path`

`value[0]` will give home, `value[1]` will give you pages and `value[2]` will give you list

Comment: url in ActivatedRoute is a `BehaviorSubject`, so one needs to use `this.route.value`.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem using

```
this.router.url
```

I get the current route with query params. A workaround I did was using this instead:

```
this.router.url.split('?')[0]
```

Not a really nice solution, but helpful.

Answer (score 7):

short version if you have **Router** imported then you can simply use some thing like

this.router.url === "/search"

else do the following

1) Import the router

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

2) Declare its entry in constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router) { }
```

3) Use its value in your function

```
yourFunction(){
    if(this.router.url === "/search"){
        //some logic
    }
}
```

@victor answer helped me, this is the same answer as him but with a little detail, as it might help someone

Answer (score 7):

This applies if you are using it with an authguard

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if(event instanceof NavigationStart){
            console.log('this is what your looking for ', event.url);  
         }
       } 
   );
```

Answer (score 6):

With angular 2.2.1 (in an angular2-webpack-starter based project) works this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  subscription: Subscription;
  activeUrl: string;

  constructor(public appState: AppState,
              private router: Router) {
    console.log('[app] constructor AppComponent');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('[app] ngOnInit');
    let _this = this;
    this.subscription = this.router.events.subscribe(function (s) {
      if (s instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        _this.activeUrl = s.urlAfterRedirects;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('[app] ngOnDestroy: ');
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

In AppComponent's template you can use e.g. {{activeUrl}}.

This solution is inspired by RouterLinkActive's code.

Comment: this is a good answer b/c if you have a wild card route that redirects back to /home event.url is not enough to match the /home route it will actually show the route that does not exist. event.urlAfterRedirects will print the actual end route. ty.

Answer (score 6):

> **WAY 1**: Using Angular: ***this.router.url***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Step 1: import the router 
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    template: 'The href is: {{href}}'
    /*
    Other component settings
    */
})
export class Component {
    public href: string = "";

    //Step 2: Declare the same in the constructure.
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.href = this.router.url;
        // Do comparision here.....
        ///////////////////////////
        console.log(this.router.url);
    }
}
```

> **WAY 2** Window.location as we do in the Javascript, If you don't want to use the router

```
this.href= window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the problem where I needed the URL path when the user is **navigating through the app** or **accessing a URL** (or refreshing on a specific URL) to display child components based on the URL.

More, I want an Observable that can be consumed in the template, so **router.url** was not an option. Nor **router.events** subscription because routing is fired before the component's template is initialized.

```
this.currentRouteURL$ = this.router.events.pipe(
     startWith(this.router),
     filter(
         (event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof Router
     ),
     map((event: NavigationEnd | Router) => event.url)
);
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: This is awesome.

Answer (score 5):

You can use in the .ts file

```
import { Route, Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

this.router.events.subscribe(value => {
      if (value instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log(value) // your current route
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

simplest way

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(router: Router) { 
      router.events.subscribe((url:any) => console.log(url));
      console.log(router.url);  <---------- to get only path eg:"/signUp"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

angular 2 rc2

```
router.urlTree.contains(router.createUrlTree(['/home']))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ActivatedRoute`](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) to get the current router

**Original Answer (for RC version)**

I found a solution on [AngularJS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular) and it's so easy!

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.subscribe((url) => console.log(url));
}
```

Here's the original answer

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/wn1h0JPrF48/zl1sHJxbCQAJ

Comment: Has been changed as of rc.2, as `url` now is no longer the URL and a string, but a `ComponentInstruction`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what is working for me in Angular 2.3.1.

```
location: any;

constructor(private _router: Router) { 

      _router.events.subscribe((data:any) => { this.location = data.url; });

      console.warn(this.location);  // This should print only path e.g. "/home"
}
```

The `data` is an object and we need the `url` property contained in that object. So we capture that value in a variable and we can use that variable in our HTML page as well. For example, I want to show a div only when user is on Home page. In this case, my router url value will be `/home`. So I can write a div in the following way:

```
<div *ngIf="location == '/home'">
This is content for the home page.
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
router.events.subscribe(e => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.currentUrl = e.url;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

This one is tested on Angular 11

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events
   .pipe(filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
   .subscribe((event: any) => {
     this.currentRoute = event.url;
     console.log(event);
   });
 }
```

Comment: This works, but what to do if I need to have it earlier, in Component Init event? And there this.router.url is '/'... :( I need this to operate with collapsing / expanding 3rd party menu and NavigationEnd, even NavigationStart is too late to affect the menu layout...

Comment: for correct typing `filter((event): event is NavigationStart => event instanceof NavigationStart),`

Answer (score 3):

In Angular2 Rc1 you can inject a `RouteSegment` and then pass it into the `.navigate()` method:

```
constructor(private router:Router,private segment:RouteSegment) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.navigate(["explore"],this.segment)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For your purposes you can use `this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot`.

```js
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){

}
```

With the help of pathFromRoot you can get the list of parent urls and check if the needed part of the URL matches your condition.

For additional information please check this article http://blog.2muchcoffee.com/getting-current-state-in-angular2-router/
or install ng2-router-helper from npm

```
npm install ng2-router-helper
```

Answer (score 3):

this is simple, in angular 2 you only need to import the *Router* library like this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Then in the constructor of the component or service you must instantiate it like this:

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {}
```

Then in any part of the code, either in a function, method, construct, whatever:

```
      this._router.events
        .subscribe(
            (url:any) => {
                let _ruta = "";
                url.url.split("/").forEach(element => {
                    if(element!=="" && _ruta==="")
                        _ruta="/"+element;  
                });
                console.log("route: "+_ruta); //<<<---- Root path
                console.log("to URL:"+url.url); //<<<---- Destination URL                    
                console.log("from URL:"+this._router.url);//<<<---- Current URL
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

To find the parent of the current route, you can obtain the `UrlTree` from the router, using relative routes:

```
var tree:UrlTree = router.createUrlTree(['../'], {relativeTo: route});
```

Then to get the segments of the primary outlet:

```
tree.root.children[PRIMARY_OUTLET].segments;
```

Answer (score 3):

As of now, I'm getting my path as follows -

```
this.router.url.subscribe(value => {
    // you may print value to see the actual object
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
    this.isPreview = value[0].path === 'preview';
})
```

Where, `router` is an instance of ***`ActivatedRoute`***

Answer (score 3):

For me the accepted answer did not work when accessing the current route within `AuthGuardService implements CanActivate` since the route isn't fully processed yet. I answered the same question here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68541653/1479486) but if you just want to copy paste from here, this is my solution:

```
const finalUrl = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.finalUrl;   
const isLoginPage = finalUrl?.root.children['primary'].segments[0]?.path === 'login';
```

Answer (score 3):

In Angular 14, if you do

```
this.router.url
```

it will always return '/'

Instead of utilizing the Router, which may not yet have the final route during the navigation lifecycle, you can use the Location service (https://angular.io/api/common/Location) and its method "path" to obtain the URL without the base href. This is a better option than using "window.location.pathname," which is not aware of Angular and will include the base href in the path.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.location.path());  // returns path

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Angular 14, if you do

```
this.router.url
```

it will always return '/'

Instead of utilizing the Router, which may not yet have the final route during the navigation lifecycle, you can use the Location service (https://angular.io/api/common/Location) and its method "path" to obtain the URL without the base href. This is a better option than using "window.location.pathname," which is not aware of Angular and will include the base href in the path.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.location.path());  // this returns the path

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
   const currentPage = this.router.url; // Current page route
  const currentLocation = (this.platformLocation as any).location.href; // Current page url
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access the current url, usually you have to wait for NavigationEnd or NavigationStart to do something. If you just subscribe to the router events the subscription will output many events in the route lifecycle. Instead, use an RxJS operator to only filter for the Event you need. The beneficial side effect of this is now we have stricter types!

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter(ev => (ev instanceof NavigationEnd))
    ).subscribe((ev: NavigationEnd) => {
      console.log(ev.url);
    });
}
```

Comment: for correct typing `filter((event): event is NavigationStart => event instanceof NavigationStart),`

Answer (score 2):

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){
    console.log(this.route.routeConfig.path);
}
```

Comment: this only gives the first segment. you need to iterate through `route.children[0]` and take the `routeConfig.path` value from each segment. If you're using auxiliary routes the `outlet` property will tell you which outlet you're in and you'd need special handling for that.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to know the url / path of every route change in a component where it's commonly rendered in every route.

1. Subscribe to the every route event.
2. If the subscribed value is the instance of NavigationEnd, then the currentPage url is router.url.

```html
currentPage: String = '';
constructor(private _router: Router) {
    this._router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        if(val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.currentPage = this._router.url;
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this could be your answer, use params method of activated route to get paramter from URL/route that you want to read, below is demo snippet

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router'; 
@Component({
})
export class Test{
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
             this.yourVariable = params['required_param_name'];
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in component file:

```
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

constructor(state: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    console.log(state.path)
}
```

in routeing file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the problem when i want to change the background according to the route. But it works only when i navigate through the website, not when i refresh the page.

In **router.events.subscribe()**, this is **events.url** when i navigate, **this.router.url** when i refresh.

Now it works :

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

public ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((events:any) => {
        let theme = '';
        if (events instanceof NavigationStart) { theme = events.url; }
        else { theme = this.router.url; }
        
        if(theme === '/videos') { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always listen to the route and also get the first loaded route, you can use this code.

```
private router = inject(Router);
currentRoute = signal<string>('');


this.router.events.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((event: any) => {
      this.currentRoute.set(event?.routerEvent?.url); // this is the current route you need
    });
```

Or you can use this code for better typescript support.

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
  if (event instanceof Scroll)
    this.currentRoute.set(event?.routerEvent?.url);
}))
```

Comment: Why did you need `any`? If `routerEvent` isn't a property then it can change anytime

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I just updated it to check for the Scroll instance.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers got it almost right. Only [Alexandres answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74848637/7082956) works.

But nonetheless, it would be more elegant to pipe the filter instead.

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  //...
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  private _selection: string | undefined;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)) //
      .subscribe((_) => {
        this._selection = this.router.url);
      });
  }
```

The event is not typesafe and accessing the URL from it would need casting. Luckily we can access the URL through the router when the navigation ended.

It is important that we access the router in ngOnInit because that is part of the initialization, not the construction.