# Angular 2 router event listener

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How to listen state change in Angular 2 router?

In Angular 1.x I used this event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function(event,toState,toParams,fromState,fromParams, options){ ... })
```

So, if I use this eventlistener in Angular 2:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => {return console.log('ok')}, false);
```

it isn't return 'ok', then change state from JS, only then browser history.back() function run.

Use router.subscribe() function as the service:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Injectable()
export class SubscribeService {
    constructor (private _router: Router) {
        this._router.subscribe(val => {
            console.info(val, '<-- subscribe func');
        })
    }
}
```

Inject service in component which init in routing:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    templateUrl: '../templates/main.html',
    providers: [SubscribeService]
})
export class MainComponent {
    constructor (private subscribeService: SubscribeService) {}
}
```

I inject this service in other components such as in this example. Then I change state, console.info() in service not working.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

**new router**

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event:Event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    }
    // NavigationEnd
    // NavigationCancel
    // NavigationError
    // RoutesRecognized
  });
}
```

**old**

Inject the Router and subscribe to route change events

```
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

class MyComponent {
  constructor(router:Router) {
    router.subscribe(...)
  }
}
```

**NOTE**

For the new router, don't forget to import `NavigationStart` from `router` module

```
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
```

because if you don't import it `instanceof` will not work and an error `NavigationStart is not defined` will rise.

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html
- [How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657)

Comment: Do I need run `router.subscribe(...)` in every class or I can run them onetime? In docs I don't understand what params I must enter in subscribe function? Can you write full example, please?

Comment: You can do it once in a global service and then inject the service wherever you want to get access.

Comment: If I inject it as service in other components it doesn't return any data

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish? I don't know where you inject the service to or how you do it.

Comment: Instead of on the component (`providers: [SubscribeService]`) add `SubscribeService` only to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [OtherProviders, SubscribeService])` and nowhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working(( Bootstrap code: `other imports... import {SubscribeService} from './services/router.subscribe';

bootstrap(GlobalAppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}), HTTP_PROVIDERS, SubscribeService]);`

Comment: It seems that this runs multiple times. @GünterZöchbauer it worked for you?

Comment: `subscribe()` means to get notified about every event therefore the callback passed to `subscribe(...)` is called every time an event is emitted.. One navigation can emit every event listed in my code. You might want to use the `filter()` operator to filter only a specific kind of event of just use `if(...)` as I did in my answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think Angular is mature enough to remove the way it was done pre-2.0.0 version (not 2.x, 4.x, 5.x differences). Both here and on any other answer I come across. Would you agree that it's good to edit the answer(s)?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović people often find old examples and then run into issues because the code doesn't work anymore. I think for them it's helpful to see that this is because Angular changed and that exmple is for an older Angular version. There is no other way to learn that, because old docs aren't available anymore.

Answer (score 12):

You can also filter events with `filter()`.

But don't *just* use `filter(e => e is NavigationEnd)`

A much better solution is to add a 'type guard' to `filter()` like this:

```
 filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
```

It contains two things:

- `e is NavigationEnd` this is the assertion you're defining a function for (this is typescript syntax and is completely stripped out of the transpiled javascript)
- `e instanceof NavigationEnd` this is the actual runtime code that checks the type

The nice thing with this is that operators further down 'the pipe', like `map` below now know the type is `NavigationEnd`, but without the type-guard you'd have a type `Event`.

If you only need to check for one event type then this is the cleanest way to do so. This also appears to be necessary in strict mode to avoid compiler errors.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `instanceof` as **@GünterZöchbauer** answered

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

or you can use a ***lazier*** approach, but remember constructor name can be changed easily while the function is still working!

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if(event.constructor.name === "NavigationStart") {
    // do something...
  }
});
```

Comment: What are your considerations for not wanting to use `instanceof`?

Comment: This approach is also brittle to minification as the constructor name could be changed, eg `event.constructor.name` might be `'A'`

Comment: This is a very unsafe method and should be heavily discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent#description)

```
import {Event, RouterEvent, Router, NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';

this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((e: any): e is RouterEvent => e instanceof RouterEvent)
).subscribe((evt: RouterEvent) => {
  if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    console.log(evt.url)
  }
})
```

Although the docs give the code `filter((e: Event)` but I changed this to `filter((e: any)` or you get linting errors in WebStorm.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Router,NavigationEnd  } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private route:Router){

  this.routeEvent(this.route);

}
routeEvent(router: Router){
  router.events.subscribe(e => {
    if(e instanceof NavigationEnd){
      console.log(e)
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular 2 router events has different classes, and what gets passed to the subscription from the `router.events` observable can either be `NavigationEnd`, `NavigationCancel`, `NavigationError`, or `NavigationStart`. The one that will actually trigger a routing update will be `NavigationEnd`.

I would stay away from using `instanceof` or `event.constructor.name` because after **minification** the class names will get mangled it will not work correctly.

You can use the router's `isActive` function instead, shown here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html

```
this.routerEventSubscription = this._router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
  if (this._router.isActive(events.url, false)) { 
    // true if the url route is active
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in angular2, go to file "app.modules.ts"->imports

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { 
         enableTracing: true
      }
)
```

in enableTracing true show routeEvents in console
in enableTracing false hide routeEvents in console

Answer (score 0):

With [@bespunky/angular-zen](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/) this has become a lot simpler...

Basically, extend the `RouteAware` class and create an `on<EventType>()` method:

```
import { Component                                        } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { RouteAware                                       } from '@bespunky/angular-zen/router-x';

@Component({
    selector   : 'app-demo',
    templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent extends RouteAware
{
    // ✨ Any router event can have a handler method.
    // See https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events for a complete list of angular's router events.

    // ✨ Use `this.router` to access the router
    // ✨ Use `this.route` to access the activated route
    // ✨ Use `this.componentBus` to access the RouterOutletComponentBus service
    
    protected onNavigationStart(event: NavigationStart): void
    {
        console.log(`Navigation started for: ${event.url}`);
    }

    protected onRoutesRecognized(event: RoutesRecognized): void
    {
        console.log('Recognized routes.');
    }
    
    protected onNavigationEnd(event: NavigationEnd): void
    {
        console.log(`Navigation ended for: ${event.url}`);
    }
}
```

Take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64864103/4371525

Comment: Well said. Improved my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To listen to all state changes, extend the default RouterOutlet and add your own logic in 'activate' and 'deactivate' handlers.

```
import {Directive} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class MyOwnRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  ...

  activate() {
    console.log('Hello from the new router outlet!');
  }
}
```

Copied from 'Custom Router Outlet' example here: https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/