# Angular 8 , js not working when press browser's back button

Tags: javascript, angular

i am working on an angular 8 project , everything work's fine until i press browser's back button , when i press back button my external `javascript` doesn't work.

i used `javascript` in several way such as ( import - require - putting them in index.html and ...) for testing but the result was the same

i also used below code to detect back

```
router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
     if (event.navigationTrigger === 'popstate') {
     // window.location.reload();
   }     
});
```

notice that i don't want to reload the entire page. is this `angular` bug ? or what ?

Comment: What do you mean `my external Javascript`? Also, it's not an AngularJS bug because you're not using AngularJS :)

Comment: Yes i mean angular :) , and my external `javascript` is my javascript file in my assets

Comment: ... but why do you have external JS files in your assets?? They're supposed to be in Angular's components

Answer (score 0):

My environment says "Property 'navigationTrigger' does not exist on type 'NavigationStart'." when I try your code, so you never enter in your if statement.

But your problem has already been posted : [Angular 2 How to detect back button press using router and location.go()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132737/angular-2-how-to-detect-back-button-press-using-router-and-location-go)

PS: Be careful to make the difference between angular 2+ and angularjs :p

Comment: my problem is not detecting the back button , i can detect it , but my javascript doesn't work after pressing back

Comment: My bad, sorry for my wrong response. But I don't understand what you mean by "javascript doesn't work after pressing". Can you be more specific ? what code should run after you pressed the button ?

Comment: i have an external javascript file that run every time page loads but when press back button i think that javascript file doesn't load anymore :)

Comment: hmm... your page isn't reload after a back button pressed event, so I think you have to reload / recall your javascript file when you catch the event. You can look after angular routing events to detect when reload your file too...