# Router State events in current angular 2 rc 6

Tags: angular, router

Seems that `OnActivate` is removed in angular 2 rc 6, what is the alternative for this.

I need to have a method which is called when all `canActivate` methods passed for a particular route changes, this method also should have the capability to accept the promise to hold the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

These are replaced by guards

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

> ```
> class UserToken {}
> class Permissions {
>   canActivate(user: UserToken, id: string): boolean {
>     return true;
>   }
> }
> @Injectable()
> class CanActivateTeam implements CanActivate {
>   constructor(private permissions: Permissions, private currentUser: UserToken) {}
>   canActivate(
>     route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
>     state: RouterStateSnapshot
>   ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
>     return this.permissions.canActivate(this.currentUser, route.params.id);
>   }
> }
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>     RouterModule.forRoot([
>       {
>         path: 'team/:id',
>         component: TeamCmp,
>         canActivate: [CanActivateTeam]
>       }
>     ])
>   ],
>   providers: [CanActivateTeam, UserToken, Permissions]
> })
> class AppModule {}
> ```

Comment: thanks, read that already, particular route can have more than one canactivate , so how to find in my canactivate function that all other canactivate are passed and i can consider this is going to be a successful naviagtion

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912932/angular-2-router-event-listener/35912966#35912966

Comment: that hooks not having the capability to hold or delay the navigation.

Comment: Please improve your question. I don't know what to do with your comments.

Comment: thanks for your help, i am trying to do http://plnkr.co/edit/pCxVob?p=preview, but exact hooks not available in angular 2

Comment: actually i have demo with this animation tomorrow, and feeling very bad about angular 2 that i can't complete this task.