# Angular 4 Component ngOnInit not called on each route request

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

I just recently started diving into Angular 4 coming from Angular 1.5.  I'm working with user routes and pulling API data from a service into a user component.

The component seems to stay static unlike controllers in 1.* where they were refreshed on each request.

Is there anyway to have the ngOnInit function called on each new route request?

My user component class:

```
// url structure: /user/:id
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit() {

      // doesn't log new id on route change
      let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
      console.log(id);

      this.route.params
        .switchMap(params => this.userService.getUser(params['id']))
        .subscribe(user => {
          // logs new id on route change
          let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
          console.log(id);

          this.user = user
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Found a solution that I think works best for my scenario.  Based on several answers and comments to my question and further investigation, subscribing to the route seems to be the way to go.  Here is my updated component:

```
export class UserComponent {

  user;
  id;

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(params => this.handleRouteChange(params));
  }

  handleRouteChange(params) {
    this.id = params['id'];

    switch (this.id) {
      case '1':
        console.log('User 1');
        break;

       case '2':
        console.log('User 2');
        break;

       case '3':
        console.log('User 3');
        break;
    }

    this.userService.getUser(this.id).
      subscribe(user => this.user = user);
  }

}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5

Comment: I have an example application here that shows several different types of routing if that helps as well: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Comment: @DeborahK, thanks for the link.  Looks like a pretty solid starter app and definitely some good coding standard examples.

Comment: Thanks @Rob I have a course that goes along with it if you are interested in that sort of thing: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents

Answer (score 3):

Angular prefers -by default- to reuse the same component instead of instanciating a new one if the route is the same but the parameters change.

**Good news** ! this is a customizable behavior, you can force instanciating a new component instance by implementing your own [`RouteReuseStrategy`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouteReuseStrategy-class.html):

```js
export class MyRouteReuseStrategy extends DefaultRouteReuseStrategy {
  shouldReuseRoute(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    let name = next.component && (next.component as any).name;
    return super.shouldReuseRoute(next, current) && name !== 'UserComponent';
  }
}
```

in your module:

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers:[{
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: MyRouteReuseStrategy}]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

(this code is more or less taken from [this article](https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5), especially the check for the `name` property which might not be very accurate...)

Note that ther might be some performance drawback when reinstanciating the same component. So maybe you'd better use the observables properties instead of the snapshot.

Comment: I found a workaround to the issue and updated my answer with it.  I believe the solution I found both preserves the performance and handles the parameters per request.  I'd be happy to hear any comments or suggestions you might have with it.  Thanks!

Comment: In Angular 2.3+ has been change some things, now is RouteReuseStrategy in core against DefaultRouteReuseStrategy and you can use it like this: <br/> shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean { let name = future.component && (future.component as any).name; return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig && name !== 'UserComponent'; } <br/> you can see it better here https://medium.com/@gerasimov.pk/how-to-reuse-rendered-component-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy-64628e1ca3eb

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is quite after the fact, but I thought it best not to leave the an incomplete solution that newcomers might implement into their projects.

In response to the original post's update: it is important that you unsubscribe from Observables once you're done using them, otherwise you risk leaving references in memory. Here's a bare example.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class Example implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  protected _routeChangeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    protected _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._routeChangeSubscription = this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(this._routeChangeHandler);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._routeChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  public _routeChangeHandler = (params: Observable<Params>) => {
    // check params here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to use **switchMap** like this:

```
this.sub = this.route.paramMap
  .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
  this.firebaseService.getProductsByCategory(params.get('category'))).subscribe(products => {
  this.products = products;
  this.count = products.length;
});
```

This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does the url look like "...?id=1" or "../:id" and you want the component to log the id each time the GET param changes?  The problem is talked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971660/angular-2-reload-route-on-param-change).  A better solution I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331592/in-angular-2-how-do-you-detect-route-changes).  I haven't tested it myself but this should work.

The second link shows how to subscribe to a route change within a component, which I think is essentially what you're trying to do.  It will allow you to handle a GET param change within `ngOnInit`.  I'm not sure if the route subscribe will run when you initally navigate to the URL, so you might want to have the function that handles the route event call a `doCheck()`, and change `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterContentInit`

ngOnInit only operates on [change detection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html), and a GET change seems not to trigger it, which is surprising to me.

Tl;dr - Subscribe to the route change event in the constructor and create a function that handles an emitted event.  The function should hold the logic you have in ngOnInit().

Comment: This is a bad advice, the solution is to not use snapshot, and only use observables. Or to implement a custom [`RouteReuseStrategy`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouteReuseStrategy-class.html).

Comment: Ah crap, I didn't look closely.  I gave a bad answer.  Don't use a snapshot.  Use the observable as n00dl3 said.  You can see an example in the stackoverflow I linked but ignore the snapshot logic.  Only look at the ngOnInit() logic.  I've edited the second link to only show the route event subscribe logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I believe I found a solution.  I updated my answer with it.  Seems to make the most sense.