# Angular 2 Communicating with <router-outlet> components

Tags: angularjs, angular, router

I have a search bar in a header component.

Beneath that, I have a "router-outlet" in that same component.

The search bar (input txtfield), once enter is pressed, needs to send the search string (event.target.value) *to* the component that resides within the router-outlet beneath it so that it can run a method to return the results.

I have no clue what the best way is to achieve this.

**UPDATED with code..**

**`app.component.html:`**

```
<div class="white-container">
     <input name="searchStr" [(ngModel)]="searchStr" (keyup.enter)="searchCourse($event)">
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**`app.component.ts:`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CourseService } from './services/courses.service';
import { Course } from './Course';

@Component({ 
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
   providers: [CourseService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

    constructor(private _courseService: CourseService) {

    }

    searchCourse(event) {
       // the user search string here...
    }

}
```

**`/course-listings/course-listings.component.ts:`**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CourseService } from './services/courses.service';
import { Course } from './Course';

@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-course-listings',
  templateUrl: './course-listings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-listings.component.css'],
  providers: [CourseService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

    course: Course[];

    constructor(private _courseService: CourseService) {

    }


    searchCourse(evt) {

        // This works once it's fired... 

        this._courseService.findCourse(evt)
            .subscribe(courses => { 
                this.course = courses; 
        });

    }


}
```

**`/services/courses.service.ts:`**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class CourseService {


    constructor(private _http:Http) {

    }

    getCourses(search) {
        return this._http.get('/api/v1/courses/'+search)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

**FIX FOUND**

Günter Zöchbauer was correct.  I used a service w/ subscribe and observables to do it. Thanks.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Can you please be more specific and add your code here or in plunkr? That would be better

Comment: I updated the original post with the code.  Gunter is eluding to using services, which honestly, I'm not exactly sure how to integrate what I need based on the link provided... and the individual below is suggesting adding a router event listener.  I'm not sure which.  Hopefully someone can help, thanks.

Comment: I've managed to get a service integrated so that it passes the user input from the main app.component, to a {{ searchStr }} property in the course-listings component view.

What I don't understand, is how I can call the method needed to display the results **when** the subscription is called (or rather, when a new search is performed).

Comment: I did it!  I realized I had to put the code inside of my previous function "searchStr" inside of the subscription within the constructor:

this.subscription = this._interactionService.searchStr$.subscribe( //listings stuff here )

Comment: Could you please post the full answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

An `event.subscriber` would be required in the constructor to pass to router-outlet.
Similar to the answer in this [Angular 2 router event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912932/angular-2-router-event-listener).

So, once the click is done, the subscriber event will be executed based on on the `navigationend` event, then the value can be accessed.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Still a bit confused on how to implement this.  Could you take a look at my updated answer with the code so I can have a more specific idea of how to integrate your approach?  Thanks.