# Get active route data inside router.events

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

How do I get active route data like params inside the subscribed router.events?

I do **not** want to subscribe to this.route.params!

```
// Catch any events in a certain component, where I subscribe to it!
this.router.events.subscribe(event =>
{ 
// The event object has only the url (when is NavigationStart/End), there is nothing useful for me


});
```

UPDATE

My question is different because I do not ask how to react to router events!

I ask for how to get the activate route params within the router.events !

Thats a difference for sure!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 router event listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912932/angular-2-router-event-listener)

Comment: No duplicate read my explanation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event =>
{ 
  console.log(this.router.routerState.root);
  console.log(this.router.routerState.root.firstChild);
  console.log(this.router.routerState.root.firstChild && this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.firstChild);
});
```

Comment: Thats not fair you want 2 solutions :P btw. I asked this before I saw what you posted in the other thread...

Comment: Life isn't fair ;p

Comment: The exact reaction I expected from you :P

Comment: I see :D Resolution for the new year - become less predictable!

Comment: damn who is upvoting my comments, do I have groupies here? I swear I dont use a 2nd account :D

Comment: Not in my special case about a pasted link in the url bar and then page load, but in general else its a solution covering 99% scenarios.

Comment: Try `setTimeout` like mentioned in the other question.

Answer (score 5):

```
merge(of(this.route.snapshot.params), this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.route),
      map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      }),
      filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
      mergeMap(route => route.params),
    )).subscribe(p => {})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(protected route: ActivatedRoute) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        let name = this.route.snapshot.params['name'];
    }
}
```

This injects the current active route, and latter you can get info from that route.