# Angular Router Event Name

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The Angular(2+) router has an [events](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#events-anchor) property that is a rxjs subject.

Once subscribed, you are able to listen for events like:

`router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => { console.log(event) });`

but the problem is you have no way to obtain the event type since it listens for all events. A hacky solution is you can inspect the constructor name of the event like:

```
router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
  if(event.constructor.name === 'NavigationStart') {
    loadingService.start();
  } else if(event.constructor.name === 'NavigationEnd') {
    loadingService.complete();
    drawerService.destroyAll();
  }
});
```

I was curious if there was a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event` is only the base class.

The concrete event values are one of

- NavigationStart
- NavigationEnd
- NavigationCancel
- NavigationError
- RoutesRecognized

You can for example use:

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
    .subscribe((event:NavigationStart) => {
      // You only receive NavigationStart events
    });
```

See also [How to detect a route change in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657)

Comment: Thanks so much! PR'd this back to the docs too! https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/15142

Comment: The best form of contributing :)

Answer (score 0):

If you install [`@bespunky/angular-zen`](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/) you could extend `RouteAware` and create an event handler method named `onNavigationEnd` like so:

```
import { Component                                        } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { RouteAware                                       } from '@bespunky/angular-zen/router-x';

@Component({
    selector   : 'app-demo',
    templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent extends RouteAware
{
    // ✨ Any router event can have a handler method.
    // See https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events for a complete list of angular's router events.

    // ✨ Use `this.router` to access the router
    // ✨ Use `this.route` to access the activated route
    // ✨ Use `this.componentBus` to access the RouterOutletComponentBus service
    
    protected onNavigationStart(event: NavigationStart): void
    {
        console.log(`Navigation started for: ${event.url}`);
    }

    protected onRoutesRecognized(event: RoutesRecognized): void
    {
        console.log('Recognized routes.');
    }
    
    protected onNavigationEnd(event: NavigationEnd): void
    {
        console.log(`Navigation ended for: ${event.url}`);
    }
}
```

[Here's a live example](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/RouterX%20Module/Route%20Aware%20Event%20Handling)

The library is open source and you can install it like this:

> npm install @bespunky/angular-zen

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple little method for testing purposes that will log out each possible event name as they happen. There can be a lot that happen fast, so I recommend also going to your DevTools "Network" tab and enabling throttling to something like DSL speeds so you can see these events happen at an easier to understand speed.

```ts
this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
  let navType = 'unknown!';
  if (ev instanceof NavigationStart) {
    navType = 'NavigationStart';
  } else if (ev instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
    navType = 'RouteConfigLoadStart';
  } else if (ev instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
    navType = 'RouteConfigLoadEnd';
  } else if (ev instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
    navType = 'RoutesRecognized';
  } else if (ev instanceof GuardsCheckStart) {
    navType = 'GuardsCheckStart';
  } else if (ev instanceof ChildActivationStart) {
    navType = 'ChildActivationStart';
  } else if (ev instanceof ActivationStart) {
    navType = 'ActivationStart';
  } else if (ev instanceof GuardsCheckEnd) {
    navType = 'GuardsCheckEnd';
  } else if (ev instanceof ResolveStart) {
    navType = 'ResolveStart';
  } else if (ev instanceof ResolveEnd) {
    navType = 'ResolveEnd';
  } else if (ev instanceof ChildActivationEnd) {
    navType = 'ChildActivationEnd';
  } else if (ev instanceof ActivationEnd) {
    navType = 'ActivationEnd';
  } else if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    navType = 'NavigationEnd';
  } else if (ev instanceof NavigationCancel) {
    navType = 'NavigationCancel';
  } else if (ev instanceof NavigationError) {
    navType = 'NavigationError';
  } else if (ev instanceof NavigationSkipped) {
    navType = 'NavigationSkipped';
  } else if (ev instanceof Scroll) {
    navType = 'Scroll';
  }
  console.log(navType, ev);
});
```

In general though for most simple applications you only need to see when the navigation has ended, like this:

```ts
this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
  let navType = 'unknown!';
  if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    //Do stuff here
  }
});
```