# ngAfterViewInit doesn't work

Tags: angular

```js
//Notes Module

////////////
const notesRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'notes',
    component: NotesComponent,
    children: [{
      path: 'detail',
      component: NotesDetailComponent
    }, {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'page1',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    }]
  }
];
//////////////
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
...
export class NotesComponent{
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('NOTES.location ', window.location);
  }
}
///////////////
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
...
export class NotesDetailComponent{
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('DETAIL.location ', window.location);
  }
}
/////////////
//NotesDetail html: <a routerLink="/notes" routerLinkActive="active">Notes</a>
//Notes html: <a routerLink="/detail" routerLinkActive="active">Detail</a>
```

When I visit routerLink="/detail I can see console: DETAIL.location but when i visit routerLink="/notes" I can't see console: NOTES.location... Why?
Help please

Maybe reason is in my parent Module:

```js
@NgModule({
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            HomeModule,
            NotesModule,
            NgbModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot([
              {
                path         : '',
                loadChildren : './home/home.module#HomeModule'}, {
                path         : 'notes',
                loadChildren : './notes/notes.module#NotesModule'}
            ])
          ],
          providers    : [homeService, AppGlobal],
          declarations : [AppComponent],
          bootstrap    : [AppComponent]
        })
```

Comment: are you not getting any errors? you should be importing `AfterViewInit ` from `@angular/core`

Comment: Perhaps a timing issue when the location is not yet updated. Try injecting the router and subscribe to the router like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912932/angular-2-router-event-listener/35912966#35912966

Comment: noup, I just need to catch my url visiting

Comment: @aaaaaaaaax10 in case your last comment was addressed to me, I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: You mean the line `'NOTES.location ...` isn't printed at all?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, yes, by refresh or by link, console does't print NOTES.location, I would like to get this comment by clicking

Comment: @aaaaaaaaax10 but the `NotesComponent` is actually created and added to the DOM?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, yes, ngOnInit works for NotesComponent

Comment: I didn't see `implement` section, your component must implement corresponding interface

Comment: @AntonLee, for what is it?

Comment: `export class NotesDetailComponent implement AfterViewInit {
}`

Comment: @aaaaaaaaax10 are you getting any errors in the browser console. I haven't seen a comment to Fabio's question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, no, console is empty

Comment: @aaaaaaaaax10 can't imaging. Can you try to reproduce in Plunker? Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular4 template. Just click the "new" button.

Comment: @AntonLee, added **export class NotesComponent implements AfterViewInit{** and/or **export class NotesDetailComponent implements AfterViewInit{** also **import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';**. unfortunately, all is same, console is empty