# Re-fetch data on route parameter change

Tags: angular, http, angular-services, angular-router

Currently, I have:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPi();
  }

  getPi(): void {
    const term = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('category');
    console.log(term);
    this.piService.getPi(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('term')).subscribe(pi => {
      this.pi = pi;
    });
  }
```

This works fine when navigationg to localhost:4200/term1. However, when I navigate to another term (localhost:4200/term2 for example), ngOnInit doesn't get fired as no other component gets loaded.

How should I watch the changes so that I can call getPi()?

Comment: Is term a route parameter?

Comment: You should subscribe to route change events.  This SO article describes it well - I think it should solve your problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912932/angular-2-router-event-listener. also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 approaches: `Observable + async pipe` or `manually subscribe/unsubscribe`

**The first approach (best IMO):**

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

export class FooComponent {
   pi$: Observable<any>;
   constructor(private piService: PiService){
      this.pi$ = this.route.paramMap.map(paramMap => paramMap.get('term')) /// map the route params to one element
     .switchMap(term => this.piService.getPi(term)) // change the main stream to the Http async request
     .share(); // prevent the request being done multiple times
   }
}
```

Furthermore, you need to use the `async` pipe in your template.

**The second approach:**

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class FooComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private termSub = Subscription.EMPTY;
   private term: any;
   ngOnInit(){
      this.termSub = this.route.paramMap.map(paramMap => paramMap.get('term')) /// map the route params to one element
      .subscribe(term => {
        this.term = term;
        this.getPi();
      });
   }

   getPi(){
     this.piService.getPi(this.term).subscribe(pi => this.pi = pi);
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
     this.termSub.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reactively re-fetch by creating a subscription variable

```
termSubscriber: Subscription;
```

and may want to import

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

and a term variable

```
term: string;
```

then subscribe to it

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.termSubscriber= this.route.params
    .subscribe(
    (params: {Params}) => {
      this.term = params['term']);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() { 
  this.termSubscriber.unsubscribe()
}
```

(will want to import OnDestroy like OnInit)

Note, if term1 is a route not a parmaeter, I'd convert it to

```
'/term/:id'
```

so you can make the id part fetchable.