# Angular Route Start and Route End Events

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i get access to the routing start and routing end events?
I want to show a Progress Bar while routing and loading data.

Can someone tell me how this works?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912932/angular-2-router-event-listener

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you prefer to work with an observable:

```
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
...
    constructor(router:Router) {
      router.events.subscribe(e => {
        if(e instanceof NavigationStart) {
          // Init Code
        }

        if(e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          // Exit Code
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, what's the different between the new ActivationStart and NavigationStart?