# Angular 6 removes query string from url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

Example

```
http://localhost:4200/login?aUasas129198
```

resolves to

```
http://localhost:4200/login
```

What should I do if I want the value after '?'

I tried doing

```
{ path: 'login/:id', component: LoginComponent },
```

But it did not work

I also tried

```
console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams);
console.log(this.route.snapshot.params);
```

But they both return empty object. What should I do now please help

Comment: Do you still see the query param in the url though? Doing `login/:id` makes id a `queryParam`.  You should also be using `this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => console.log(queryParams))`

Also, apparently there's no value of the queryParam that you're specifying.

Comment: No the query param disappears

Comment: No I can't the part after '?' comes from another solution and I need to interpret the data after '?'. I do not have any choice

Comment: Use `param` instead of a `queryParam` in that case. Also make sure to subscribe to `route.params` instead of using `route.snapshot.params`

Comment: subscribing to route.params returns empty object too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it’s unavoidable that Angular redirects you immediately and loses the query parameters, you could subscribe to router events and on each `NavigationStart` for `login` route get a hold of route’s [`queryParamMap`](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route) or [`snapshot.paramMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51808539/247441) before they’re lost in redirection, then you can e.g. pass it to a service and do whatever you wanted to do with it.

Or, as another alternative, you could look into configuring your router with `queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'`, in which case it should pass the query params to the next route (see the section in Angular docs linked below for more on this).

I worked with a project that made use of query params in Angular 5, IIRC I don’t think it would redirect on its own so I’d recommend to look elsewhere in your project but I may be wrong.

#### See also

- [Routing & Navigation → Query parameters and fragments](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments) in Angular docs
- [Angular Route Start and Route End Events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48444031/247441) on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

Actually, You are not passing the value in any key:

```
http://localhost:4200/login?aUasas129198
```

The proper way should be:

```
http://localhost:4200/login?anykey=aUasas129198
// get it as
// this._ActivatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe()
```

If you are using the URI as you shown in your question as:

```
{ path: 'login/:id', component: LoginComponent }
```

Then you should pass the value to id as:

```
http://localhost:4200/login/aUasas129198
// remember the '/' after the login that you didn't use.
// get it as
// this._ActivatedRoute.snapshot.params.id
```

Comment: As I said in the comments I cannot change the url structure. Is there a way in angular to interpret url without proper query param key?

Comment: @SanjayIdpuganti As you said, **I can't change the part after '?'**, but you can change before `?`.