# Optimal way to create a JSON Query Parameter in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an application with **Angular 2.x** written in typescript where I need to create a JSON Structure dynamically based on User Interactions with the UI. The JSON Structure consists of key:value parameters and arrays. This JSON Structure is then sent to an API as HTTP Parameter.

A simplified example for the JSON structure:

```
{
  'key_1': 'param_1',
  'key_2:  'param_2',
  'array_key_1': [
     {
       'key_1_1': 'value_1_1',
       'key_1_2': 'value_1_2
     },
     {
       'key_2_1': 'value_2_1',
       'key_2_2': 'value_2_2'
     }
  ],
  'array_key_2': [
           {
       'key_1_1': 'value_1_1',
       'key_1_2': 'value_1_2,
       'someArray': [...]
     },
     {
       'key_2_1': 'value_2_1',
       'key_2_2': 'value_2_2'
       'someArray': [..]
     }
  ]
}
```

This JSON Structure is used as a query for a Database.

#### Current Implementation

Initially I declare a `public sqlJSON: Object = {}` in the component and use `ngOnInit()` LifeCycleHook to initialize the empty arrays (this is needed because if not initialized, Angular will not recognize the array when an entry is pushed into it).

I use the `ngOnChanges` LifeCycleHook to reset the JSON Structure if the user changes the to another topic of interest. For instance, `sqlJSON['array_key_1] = []` and so on.

#### Query

Is there a better way to use create such JSON Structures? For instance can one use `localStorage` for the same keeping in mind that the JSON might turn out to be very *large* if the user interacts with the UI alot? Also are there any memory constraints while storing such JSON Structures in `localStorage`.

It is also worth informing that since the Backend Requirements keep changing, the above mentioned JSON Structure needs to keep adding/removing new key:value parameters.

Can an `interface` be used for the building this JSON? I think since parameters keep added/removed an `interface` would be more adaptable.

Comment: Hi, I'd subscribe to Router events change as it's already there and less error prone. Please read this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912932/angular-2-router-event-listener
https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Hi, my query is not whether there is a route change within my application. To clarify, the user interacts within the same route of the component and within the component there is _dynamic JSON_ that gets changed with every interaction. Hence your link does not answer my question

Comment: Ok yes it doesn't help. For storing 'larger' amount of data instead of `localStorage` you can use `IndexedDb`. This way you can store datas on interaction and query it when you need to.