# Angular 7 Set Router Animation trigger dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Use case, I have two animations: fader and slideLeft.

I would like to be able to switch them out.
I was trying to set the animationTrigger dynamically? but can't quite figure it out?

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { fader, slideLeft } from '../route-animations';
import { AnimationTriggerMetadata } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
 selector: 'secure',
 templateUrl: './secure.component.html',
 animations: [
  fader,
  slideLeft
 ]
})
export class SecureComponent implements OnInit {
// nav bar open or small
isOpen = true;
animationTrigger: AnimationTriggerMetadata ;

constructor(
) {
}

prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
 console.log("route animation - secure", outlet);
 return outlet.isActivated ? outlet.activatedRoute : '';
}


}
```

component.html

```
<div [@animationTrigger]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
 <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: You should consider using [Router and subscribing to the events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912966/7264565).

Comment: hmmm, guess this is harder than I thought?

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to understand/solve because we have no detail about the animation itself. You might be able to provide a single animation that controlls both triggers. Can you provide a video and/or can you add your animation metadata.