# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number' in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, null, syntax-error

I'm trying to create an app in Angular but I get a **"Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number' error**. The problem is that if I try to correct this error by using the "any" parameter in 'id', then the app does not show me the detail when I click on either panel on the front page.

The desired result would be that if I click on any panel:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YViGs.png)

The app should show me the detail:

[Desired result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeJr0.png)

This is my code:

service.ts:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Ejercicio } from './ejercicio';
import { EJERCICIOS } from './collection-ejercicios';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EjercicioService {

  constructor() { }

  getEjercicios():Observable<Ejercicio[]>{
    return of(EJERCICIOS);
  }
  getEjercicio(id:number):Observable<Ejercicio>{
    console.log("Id solicitado: "+id);
    return of(EJERCICIOS.find(ejercicio=>ejercicio.id===id)!);
  }

}
```

ejercicio.component.ts:

```
import { Ejercicio } from '../ejercicio';
import { EjercicioService } from '../ejercicio.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ejercicios',
  templateUrl: './ejercicios.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ejercicios.component.css']
})
export class EjerciciosComponent implements OnInit {

  ejercicios!: Ejercicio[];
  ejercicioSeleccionado:Ejercicio | undefined;

  constructor(private ejercicioService: EjercicioService) {
    console.log("---Componente Ejercicios CREADO ---");
  }

    getEjercicios():void {
      this.ejercicioService.getEjercicios().subscribe(ejercicios=>this.ejercicios=ejercicios);
    }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log("---Componente Ejercicios[ngOnInit] ---");
   this.getEjercicios();
  }

  onSelectEjercicio(ejercicio: Ejercicio): void {
    console.log("Ejercicio seleccionado="+ejercicio.id);
    this.ejercicioSeleccionado=ejercicio;
  }
}
```

ejercicio-detalle.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Ejercicio } from '../ejercicio';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { EjercicioService } from '../ejercicio.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ejercicio-detalle',
  templateUrl: './ejercicio-detalle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ejercicio-detalle.component.css']
})
export class EjercicioDetalleComponent implements OnInit {


  ejercicio!: Ejercicio;
  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private ejercicioService: EjercicioService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEjercicio();
  }
  getEjercicio():void{
    const id=this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.ejercicioService.getEjercicio(id).subscribe(ejercicio=>this.ejercicio=ejercicio)
  }
}
```

This is the line where I get the eror message:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PECFU.png)

I have managed to remove the error by adding id: any in the ejercicio.service.ts file, but in that case when I compile the application I don't get the desired result (the app does not show me the detail when I click on the front panels).

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Comment: try `getEjercicio(parseInt(id!))`

Comment: This also solved the issue with data not displaying properly on the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's possible that `paramMap` will *not* contain `id`, you must check in your code to ensure that it is actually defined. To fix this particular issue,  you'll simply need to do a check that it exists, like so:

```js
getEjercicio(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) { // Add your check here. "id !== null" would work, too.
       const idAsNum = parseInt(id);
       
       // Check if this string is Not a Number.
       // If so, return, we can't continue.
       if (idAsNum === NaN) {
          return;
       }

       this.ejercicioService
          .getEjercicio(idAsNum)
          .subscribe(ejercicio => this.ejercicio = ejercicio)
    }
  }
```

This may not fix the issue you are seeing with the data not displaying. You may need to use an Angular [route listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912966/4914803) to make it work as intended.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue persists even if I add that code it's still saying that the argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. Regarding the data not displaying, I have added the router to my app-routing.module.ts file but without success.

Comment: @Elvis, sorry about that, I added the code to parse it as a number as well. I'm assuming it is an integer. You could also use the syntax `const idAsNum = +id` to do the conversion.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. Your code also works now, and also solves the issue with displaying the data on the front page.