# How to get only path from full url string

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When using Router ( `this.router.url`) I am get the string `/MyRouterName?type=abc`, sometime `/MyRouterName` if not have parameter

Can I only get the path `/MyRouterName` (for all cases) from the full url?

Comment: It is hard to accept that angular is not providing a simple `pathname` property on the router state and instead we need to iterate over the url segments or use a regex to split the url.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the activated route component's snapshot to get this url.

```js
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
     constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

        console.log("routes");
        console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url); // array of states
        console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path); 
    }
```

Link to original SO answer by Jose G Varanam [How to get current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route)

Comment: I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined" for the last `console.log` statement

Comment: `snapshot.url` doesnt return the states from the root on. I have this solution `this.route.snapshot.pathFromRoot.map(o => o.url[0]).join('/')`

Comment: This answer is not sufficient, as @NinjaOnSafari pointed out, for nested routes, one would need to iterate over the different snapshots starting from root.

Comment: Please, note, that you can use `activatedRoute` only in routable components, components within `<router-outlet>`. In another way, use `router: Router` and call its property `router.url` to get the full URL. To get urlSegments array, call `router.parseUrl(this.router.url).root.segments`;

Comment: You may want full path including trailing hash and you may also not be a fan of imports. How I do it is: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391677/how-to-get-only-path-from-full-url-string#67186024)

Comment: I cannot use this solution, as in mobile Safari, the activatedRoute.snapshot.url.length equals 0 (strangely, must be a browser bug?)

Answer (score 17):

if you reload page , you can not get route path by Router or ActivatedRoute .
You can use `window.location.pathname` instead of that.

Comment: with this you will have side effects in your functions and move away from the router state being your SSOT.

Comment: what kind of side effects

Answer (score 11):

The answer user5049376 has given didn't work for me. the url property was undefined.

```
console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path);
```

instead of that I used the firstChild property.

```
console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.url[0].path);
```

Comment: I can also confirm that `activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path` throws a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`. The solution that worked for me is `activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.url[0].path`. I am using Angular 4.0.0 and Angular CLI 1.1.0.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me.

Import this :

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

then pass it to the constructor :

```
path: any;

constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.path = this.router.url;
  console.log(this.path);
}
```

Comment: If there is a querystring that is included in the path, so it's not really just the path.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to use the other responses and they all end up with **undefined**.

So I did this:

```
#AppComponent
constructor(private router: Router){
  // Subscribe to RouterEvents
  this.router.events
  .subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      // Could add more chars url:path?=;other possible
      const urlDelimitators = new RegExp(/[?//,;&:#$+=]/);
      let currentUrlPath = event.url.slice(1).split(urlDelimitators)[0];
      console.log('URL_PATH: ', currentUrlPath);
    }
  });
}
```

I subscribe to the router changes so when NavitionStartEvent happens a new URL_PATH is found.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this simple and effective?

```
let path = this.router.url.split("?")[0];
```

Comment: this will include fragments aswell

Answer (score 3):

For me, this is the cleanest solution I managed to do. I hope it helps

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){}

getUrlWithoutParams(){
   let urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
   urlTree.queryParams = {}; 
   return urlTree.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Following approach worked for me in Angular 8**

**URL**

> http://localhost:4200/admin/audit_trail

**What I wanted to extract?**

> admin

**Code**

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
    const path = this.route.snapshot.parent.routeConfig.path;
}

// path = 'admin'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE you can use the [URL class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to do reverse-engineer the url components from the string:

```
(new URL(this.router.url), 'x:/').pathName
```

Considering your example, the code above would yield only the "/MyRouterName" part of "/MyRouterName?type=abc".

Note: the 'x:/' part only exists to satisfy the URL class' need for a protocoll (which this.router.url doesn't provide).

Answer (score 0):

Below code works with both: non-hash and hash (e.g https://site/#/user)urls

```
public openInNewTab(router: Router, namedRoute ) {
      let newRelativeUrl = router.createUrlTree([namedRoute]);
      let baseUrl = window.location.href.replace(router.url,'');

      window.open(baseUrl + newRelativeUrl, '_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answers here... Allow me to add an alternative:

#### The [`UrlReflectionService`](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/docs/zen/injectables/UrlReflectionService.html) provided by the [`@bespunky/angular-zen`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bespunky/angular-zen) library.

```js
import { Component            } from '@angular/core';
import { UrlReflectionService } from '@bespunky/angular-zen/router-x';

@Component({
    selector   : 'app-demo',
    templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
    styleUrls  : ['./demo.component.css']
})
export class DemoComponent
{   
    constructor(public urlReflection: UrlReflectionService)
    {
        // use properties (e.g. `routeUrl`, `queryString`) from `this.urlReflection`
        // to extract parts of the current url

        // use methods (e.g. `routeOf()`, `queryStringOf()`) from `this.urlReflection`
        // to extract parts of any url 
    }
}
```

[Live Example](https://bs-angular-zen.web.app/RouterX%20Module/Url%20Reflection)

#### TLDR 1

The service facilitates all kinds of url extraction and manipulation operation, and even exposes the `RegEx` objects it internally uses in case you need further customization.

#### TLDR 2

Remember to:

1. > npm install @bespunky/angular-zen
2. Import `RouterXModule` (for root or child).