# how to get particular string from url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

example:https://www.google.com/upload/images/2021-5-3/3fde799e-1b53-33aa-b6b4-181d00a26a1f/output-001.svg

I want to get only "upload/images"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match everything between 3rd and 5th slash, e.g.:

```
let url = "https://www.google.com/upload/images/2021-5-3/3fde799e-1b53-33aa-b6b4-181d00a26a1f/output-001.svg";
let result = url.replace(/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/([^/]*\/[^/]*).*/, "$1");
```

which results in

```
"upload/images"
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the URL class you can get the pathname.

```
let url = new URL("https://www.google.com/upload/images/2021-5-3/3fde799e-1b53-33aa-b6b4-181d00a26a1f/output-001.svg");
$ url.pathname -> "/upload/images/2021-5-3/3fde799e-1b53-33aa-b6b4-181d00a26a1f/output-001.svg"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = window.location.href;
let pathname = url.split('.com/')[1]
let param = pathname.split('/');
let result = `${param[0]}/${param[1]}`
```

This is a bit lengthy but gives you required result.

Comment: This would break for any non-.com TLD.

Comment: in that case we can use window.location.pathname instead of href.

Comment: True, but this also ignores the fact that the original post does not describe whether this is occurring in a scenerio where there is a window object, or in some other instance.

Comment: yes, you are right, it works only in the code that has window object, mostly browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way to get the route (the URL without the domain):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    template: 'Play with the routes'
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.router.url);
    }
}
```

From this point onward is pretty easy to play with the route and get the pieces you want: for example, split the string when you find the `/` and join only the pieces that you want.

You can also think of use `UrlSegment` (documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSegment)).

You can also have a look at this other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39219771/2275011).