# Get route details from ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In an Angular2 guard you get access to an ActivatedRouteSnapshot object. Is there an easy way to recreate the array that can be used as a routeLink?

So when the guard is fired for the route `/section/:id/action` the ActivatedRouteSnapshot contains a bunch of information, but to create a link to that specific route you need an array ['/section', '<:id value>', 'action'].

Ofcourse I can just split and whatnow, but considering the complexity that is possible when taking parameters into account I prefer to use the 'standard' way if there is one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the url function on the ActivatedRoute snapshot. Use it like this.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(){
    const urlArr = this.route.snapshot.url;
    // urlArr = ["blah", "blah", "blah"]
}
```

There's a bunch of other ways you could do it, but ActivatedRoute snapshot is how I would. [How to get current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route)

Comment: Doesn't help when dealing with `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` in guard's `canActivate` :(

Comment: That is ActivatedRoute, not ActivatedRouteSnapshot.