# How to get Route Params in Angular2 rc5?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angular

I am getting a simple parameter via the router, using Angular2 RC5. The parameter is just a name. In app.routes.ts, I set the route parameter to "directory/:ninja".

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { DirectoryComponent } from "./directory/directory.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [

    { path: 'directory/:ninja', component: DirectoryComponent },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }

];

export const APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

**directory.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-directory',
  templateUrl: './directory.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./directory.component.css']
})
export class DirectoryComponent implements OnInit {

  ninja: string;    

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) { 

    this.ninja = route.snapshot.params['ninja'];

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**directory.component.html**

```
{{ninja}}
```

Whenever I access http://localhost:4200/directory/richard, it redirects me to the ROOT URL. Richard is the name of the ninja.

It should display the name of the ninja in directory.component.ts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route/40115938#40115938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Import

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
```

2) Constructor

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,.......
```

3) Subscribe

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log('Param whatever: ', params['whatever']);
  this.whatever = params['whatever'];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, i am still not able to get the parameter to the component.

Comment: cay you put it into plnkr? you can take this one as angular2-basis: http://plnkr.co/edit/XXeu7zi0ULY6sfdw6MYc