# Angular 2 Get current route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

So I need somehow check if I am on home page and do something and in other pages don't do that. Also that component imported on all of pages.

How can I detect on that component if I'm on home page???

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this,

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router:Router) { ... }

    ngOnInit() {
        let currentUrl = this.router.url; /// this will give you current url

        // your logic to know if its my home page.
    }

}
```

Comment: except that this always shows `/` as the URL... ie it is not showing the current page, only the root of the site

Comment: Works correctly for me. It's displaying /home when I'm in HomeComponent.

Comment: @SerjSagan you must be having `{ path: '', component: RootComponent }` as the root page...

Comment: { path: 'about', component: About, data: {title: 'About'} } have this but still im getting  /

Comment: I think there is some confusion here related to where this code is used. If you use it in the `app.component` which hosts the `<router-outlet>` tag it will always return `/` while in the child components it works properly.

Comment: @RaulA That's the issue I'm having. Do you know of a way to get the non-root current route from the app component?

Comment: According to [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide): Dont mark private variables with an _underscore

Comment: @YonaAppletree - I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43513784/185123) answers how to get the route in the app component

Answer (score 40):

Try it

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({...})

export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private router:Router) {

    router.events.subscribe(event => {

      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
        console.log("current url",event.url); // event.url has current url
        // your code will goes here
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: // your code will goes here
                if (event.url === '/') {
                    this.showComponent = false;
                } else {
                    this.showComponent = true;
                }

Comment: Working Fine as of 22nd March 2018

Answer (score 5):

Try any of these from the native window object.

```
console.log('URL:' + window.location.href);
console.log('Path:' + window.location.pathname);
console.log('Host:' + window.location.host);
console.log('Hostname:' + window.location.hostname);
console.log('Origin:' + window.location.origin);
console.log('Port:' + window.location.port);
console.log('Search String:' + window.location.search);
```

NOTE: DO NOT USE THIS IN SERVER SIDE RENDERING

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular Location Service.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

You can access the path using:

```
location.path();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the complete URL, use LOCATION instance as follows :-

```
([Location][1])location.href = https://test-mydomain.com/#/securelogin?name=batman
```

& if you want relative URL, use ROUTER instance follow :-

```
this.router.url = securelogin?name=batman
```

Follow the complete snippet as follows based on angular 4:-

```
constructor( private router: Router) {
  console.log(this.router.url);
/**
* securelogin?name=batman
*/

  console.log(location.href);
/**
* https://test-mydomain.com/#/securelogin?name=batman
*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was about to answer this question but I have the same answer with BigBrother. This answer is for those who uses "#" on their URL as it only returns "/" on some router location code.

This is a sample code of one of my project:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event)  => {
  if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.currentPage =  event.url;
      if ( event.url != '/admin') {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalSurveyComponent,this.config);
        }, 3000);
      }
  }
});
```

So Pop up will only show if the current route is not "/admin"

Answer (score -3):

```
import { RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    console.log("Current Url Path", state);
}
```

Comment: While this snippet may answer the question some explanation would certainly improve it.

Comment: In 4.4.4, [RouterStateSnapshot](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.4/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L314-L350) is not an injectable service.