# How to get Route data into App Component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have defined some route data in my app routing module like below:

```
    const appRoutes:Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent, data:[{PageName:"Login Page"}]}]
```

I want to get the data globally so that I can use appRoutes in app.component.ts to get the URL redirection related information as below:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Welcome';
  constructor(public router: Router, public authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        console.log("Url",event.urlAfterRedirects);
        console.log("Page Name", router[PageName]); //Not working
      }
```

I tried injecting ActivatedRoute but it's not getting updated after each redirection.

Is there anyway, where I can configure page name and get it in global `app.component.ts`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to `filter` and loop your events instead of `subscribe`

```
constructor(router:Router, route:ActivatedRoute) {
    router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .forEach(e => {
        this.title = route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data['PageName'];
    });
}
```

Please check the following working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/rBToHRaukDlrSKcLGavh?p=info

Comment: I added the above code to my app.component.ts . I am getting the value as undefined.

Comment: Can you create a plunker? It's hard to help you like that. As you see my working demo works, so we are very close to fix your issue :)

Comment: I apologise Its a big project with multiple modules i cant create plunker out of it.

Comment: ok, I understand :) Now I see a small difference between my example and your code. In the Routes array for the `data` property you are using an array: `data:[{PageName:"Login Page"}]` Can you try my example with an object: `data:{PageName:"Login Page"}`. Maybe for that, you receive `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks Eftimov, It worked :) I changed array to object and since i have multiple modules in  project i have add some more code as below : var pageName = route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data['trackPageName'];
        if(!pageName) pageName = route.root.firstChild.snapshot.firstChild.data['trackPageName'];

Comment: I am glad to hear that :)

Comment: this is the updated answer for future angulars, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269666/angular-get-route-data-in-app-component

Answer (score 25):

This code was written by Todd Motto (Google Developer Expert) to access route data in a parent component or app component. Works like a gem.

```
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router'
import { filter, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => this.route),
    map(route => {
      while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild
      return route
    }),
    filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary'),
    mergeMap(route => route.data)
  ).subscribe(data =>
    console.log('data', data)
  )
}
```

See: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

In his example he is using route data to set the page title in app component.

Why accessing route data in a parent is so complicated I'll never know!

Comment: This looks quite painful/depressing. Like, why is it this difficult? I could never have figured this out on my own ;(

Comment: Oh god, it actually works. This is the only one that works. I think it might be because to access the current route data in the primary outlet from a parent component that holds the outlet is a little more complicated, especially if you take into account the fact that there may be multiple routers. But it also makes me lose a bit of confidence in my own abilities. I guess I'll keep trying and keep learning...

Answer (score 23):

If you had statically routed using Router object like below:

```
{
  path: '',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  component: NameComponent,
  data: { variableName: 'variableValue' }
},
```

On ngOnInit() you can use ActivatedRoute object to recover the data you passed from Router definition:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.localVariable = this.route.snapshot.data['variableName'];
}
```

Obs: I am using Angular 5!

Comment: this.route is instance of what?

Comment: can you post a stackblitz link?

Comment: best answer by far!

Comment: @FurqanShakir route is ActivatedRoute from @angular/router

Comment: This approach works for components that are part of the route component being routed. 

This approach does *not* work from within the root app component itself. when `ngOnInit` is called on the root app component as requested, `snapshot.data` is an empty object.

Comment: @Randolpho That's true, it's because the snapshot is for the part of the route that belongs to the component. `AppComponent` is not typically passed as a route, that's why it doesn't have that property. As @pablo mentioned, this is only in the case where you defined the component in routing to have route data. If you do need this functionality from AppComponent, you're doing something globally and you'll need to drill through route data as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50268145/227299

Comment: Works for me only when using *root.firstChild*  like in `route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data['variableName']`

Answer (score 4):

For Angular 5+

This service retrieves data on the current route: (in my case "title")

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class AppRoutingService {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  public getRouteTitle(): string {
    return this.getRouteData("title");
  }

  private getRouteData(data: string): any {
    const root = this.router.routerState.snapshot.root;
    return this.lastChild(root).data[0][data];
  }

  private lastChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): ActivatedRouteSnapshot {
    if (route.firstChild) {
      return this.lastChild(route.firstChild);
    } else {
      return route;
    }
  }
}
```

Component Logic:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";

// SERVICES
import { AppRoutingService } from "../../shared/services/app-routing.service";

@Component()
export class NavSubmenuComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title: string = "";
  routerEvents: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, private appRoutingService: AppRoutingService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = this.appRoutingService.getRouteTitle();

    this.routerEvents = this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.title = this.appRoutingService.getRouteTitle();
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routerEvents.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt the RouterService be called AppRoutingService instead?

Answer (score 3):

In my case this work for angular 8:

`onActivate(outlet)` in `<router-outlet>` will be called automatically every time when the route is activated.

in html

```
<router-outlet (activate)='onActivate(outlet)' #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
```

in component

```
onActivate(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    outlet.activatedRoute.data.pipe(map(data => console.log('Router data', data))).toPromise().then();
  }
```

Dont forget import

```
import {RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to wait until the ngAfterViewInit event you can link to the router outlet using viewchild.

i.e.

```ts
  @ViewChild('router')
  private routerOutlet: RouterOutlet;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.routerOutlet.activateEvents
      .pipe(
        map(() => this.routerOutlet
          .activatedRouteData
        )
      )
    .subscribe((data) => {
        // Code 
    });
  }
```

```html
<router-outlet #router="outlet"></router-outlet>
```