# How to access static data added for particular route in angular 2/4 in service?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'somepath',
        component: SomeComponent,
        data: {
            showSidebar: true,
            title: 'test'
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'somepath2',
        component: SomeComponent2,
        data: {
            showSidebar: false,
            title: 'test2'
        }
    }
];
```

How can I access data object from currently activates route?
If my current route is localhost:4200/app/somepath2 then I want to access 
 data: { showSidebar: false, title: 'test2' }

Comment: I have almost the same question. But I need to get `data` for ALL such routes of the components in my menu. I cannot find the corresponding info anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **`this.route.snapshot.data`**

Inject router in the constructor

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute)

ngOnInit() {
    const myData = this.route.snapshot.data;
}
```

Comment: What is `this.route` and how do I inject it? Any documentation links?

Comment: `snapshot.data` is giving me back an empty object `{}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512695/how-to-get-route-data-into-app-component-in-angular-2/43513784

Comment: I am not the OP, sorry.

Comment: Haha ok  now I seee