# How do I refresh the current route?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am developing an app in [NativeScript with Angular](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/)

When I want to navigate to another route I simply programmatically declare:

```
this.router.navigate(['/my-details']);
```

However, when I am on the my-details route and I want to refresh the route.

I have tried calling the route again with the same method as above, as adding a parameter to the route such as /refresh, but they both do not work.

How do I refresh/navigate to the current route?

Comment: Try to reload your state by "**$state.reload();**".

Comment: how do you access $state in nativescript?

Comment: `$state.reload()` is in angular1 I don't think its similar in angular2, not sure if this is the same as your use case but it might do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42538251/angular-2-get-current-route

Comment: unfortunately, that just gets the current route, I know that route already. I just want to reload the current one.

Comment: Why you have to refresh the route? you can reload the data, the view will be refreshed!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use pullToRefresh? Although you have a detail view and not a list view it is possible to implement it there: https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-pulltorefresh#html