# Get current url in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I get the current url in Angular 4? I've searched the web for it a lot, but am unable to find solution.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/Router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { OtherComponent } from './other/other.component';
import { UnitComponent } from './unit/unit.component';

@NgModule ({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TestComponent,
    OtherComponent,
    UnitComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: 'test',
            component: TestComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'unit',
            component: UnitComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'other',
            component: OtherComponent
        }
    ]),
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced -->
<div>
    <h1>Welcome to {{title}}!!</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a routerLink="/test">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
             <a routerLink="/unit">Unit</a>  
        </li>
        <li>
            <a routerLink="/other">Other</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent{
    title = 'Angular JS 4';
    arr = ['abcd','xyz','pqrs'];
}
```

**other.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-other',
  templateUrl: './other.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./other.component.css']
})

export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {

    public href: string = "";
    url: string = "asdf";

    constructor(private router : Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.href = this.router.url;
        console.log(this.router.url);
    }
}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    route: string;
    currentURL='';

    constructor() { 
        this.currentURL = window.location.href; 
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Right now I am getting console issue after clicking on **other** link

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Router!
```

Comment: Which url ??? browser url and please add some code the things you tried in so to understand you question in more details

Comment: Yes, current page url in browser

Comment: @MaciejTreder : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route) gone through this link already, it didn't worked.

Comment: Ok. Got your point. Did you try the solution from the answer?

Comment: How to access **this.route** variable in app.component.html view file?
I want to echo current url in app.component.html file.
`export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
 route: string;
 constructor(location: Location, router: Router) {
  router.events.subscribe((val) => {
         **this.route** = location.path();
     });
 }
 ngOnInit() {
 }
}`

Comment: you can use as import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  currentURL='';
  constructor() {
        this.currentURL=window.location.href;
    }
}

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar: thanks a lot. It worked, by interpolating **{{this.currentURL}}** in view file.

Comment: @NilamDhok: I have added the same code in my answer. You can mark it as answer.

Comment: You got a typo in `import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/Router';` it should be `@angular/router`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue in plunkr. Everything works: https://plnkr.co/edit/0x3pCOKwFjAGRxC4hZMy?p=preview

Answer (score 487, accepted):

With pure JavaScript:

`console.log(window.location.href)`

Using Angular:

`this.router.url`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    template: 'The href is: {{href}}'
    /*
    Other component settings
    */
})
export class Component {
    public href: string = "";

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.href = this.router.url;
        console.log(this.router.url);
    }
}
```

The plunkr is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/0x3pCOKwFjAGRxC4hZMy?p=preview

Comment: Got error : Property 'router' does not exist on type <component_name>' :(

Comment: Did you provide router to the component constructor?

Comment: `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-other',
  templateUrl: './other.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./other.component.css']
})

export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {

   public href: string = "";

    constructor(protected router : Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.href = this.router.url;
        console.log(this.router.url);
    }
}`

Comment: Do you have RouterModule imported? Check out this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/bmT3HSXdTmgAguiIL6zE?p=preview

Comment: Did you check plunker? Is it working on your end?

Comment: Yes I checked plunker. Even imported RouterModule in app.module.ts file, but now I'm getting error like: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Router!

**app.module.ts**

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Router!
Error: No provider for Router!` in console.

Comment: How did you import RouterModule? All in all, do you really need route from `router`? `window.location.href` is not enough in your case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149607/discussion-between-maciej-treder-and-nilam-dhok).

Comment: @MaciejTreder this method `this.router.url` you mentioned will be trigger when page is reloading. is there any other way to get path `URL` without reloading page in `Angular 4` ?

Comment: @FaiZalDong Yes. It is. I will update my answer in near future. So far you can find example in my boilerplate, here: https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-pwa/commit/625fbd7bfca089fecadb12d4b024dacd4348394b

Comment: `window.location.href` is returning the absolute url of the page (including protocol and domain) while `this.router.url` is returning the relative path inside the application... I really do not understand how it is possible that this is the accepted answer as this solution is returning 2 completely different results!!! I also do not understand how it is possible that is marked as duplicated as the linked question is asking for the route url while here the question is asking for the absolute path

Comment: @Ferie comment above it correct. inaccurate answer

Comment: this.router.url doesn't work as it is. follow this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320416/angular-router-url-returns-slash

Comment: While in fact I'm on some page of my Angular app, `this.router.url` for a menu subcomponent returns me '\'  each time... The truth is somewhere else...

Comment: Well, one way it can happen, @Ferie, is that browsers and angular and JS evolve over time. Perhaps at the time of the answer, the answer was correct from the perspective of angular and browsers at the time? Otherwise, I'm SMH with you.

Comment: Thank you @Richard it worked for what I initially needed

Comment: This is not returning the full url

Comment: Wrong waye it's return just "/" waste of time

Comment: Downvoted because it does not answer the question; A "full URL" implies at least a protocol, host and path, but `router.url` returns only the path part of the full URL.

Answer (score 82):

You can make use of location service available in @angular/common and via this below code you can get the location or current URL

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-top-nav',
  templateUrl: './top-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-nav.component.scss']
})
export class TopNavComponent implements OnInit {

  route: string;

  constructor(location: Location, router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if(location.path() != ''){
        this.route = location.path();
      } else {
        this.route = 'Home'
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

here is the reference link from where I have copied thing to get location for my project.
https://github.com/elliotforbes/angular-2-admin/blob/master/src/app/common/top-nav/top-nav.component.ts

Comment: You can just emit the first event using first() operator: `router.events.pipe(first()).subscribe((val) => {...});`

Comment: The only concern is that when I console.log it runs multiple times.

Comment: You can also write it like this: 
router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      const thereIsAPath = location.path() != '';
      const defaultPath = '/';
      const currentPath = location.path();
      thereIsAPath
        ? this.changePageBackground(currentPath)
        : this.changePageBackground(defaultPath);
    });

Comment: constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(): void {

  this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.currentUrl = event.url;
    }
  });
}

Answer (score 6):

**other.component.ts**

So final correct solution is :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 

/* 'router' it must be in small case */

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-other',
      templateUrl: './other.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./other.component.css']
    })

    export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {

        public href: string = "";
        url: string = "asdf";

        constructor(private router : Router) {} // make variable private so that it would be accessible through out the component

        ngOnInit() {
            this.href = this.router.url;
            console.log(this.router.url);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is the correct solution? I would prefer to get a array of type `UrlSegment[]` instead to work with it with the `Router`

Comment: @ndgeek Better would be to have `public href: string = ""` replaced by a `get` property. This way there's no need to assign the value in `ngOnInit` whilst also having an always up to date router URL.

As such: `get href(); string {  return this.router.url; }`. Also there's no need as setting it `public` because that's the default.