# Angular router url returns slash

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying to get the current router path by using Router, but when i do `console.log(this.router.url)` it returns "/", although i'm on the "/login".
But when i'm consoling the entire `this.router` object, there is the property `url` which has value "/login".

here is my code from app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.router);
  }

}
```

app.module.routing.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {NotFoundComponent} from './not-found/not-found.component';
import {AuthGuard} from './auth/auth-guard.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './first/first.module#FirstModule'},
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
  { path: '404', component: NotFoundComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppModuleRouting {}
```

and the FirstModule routing:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {FirstComponent} from './first.component';
import {AuthGuard} from '../auth/auth-guard.service';

const firstRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: FirstComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children:[
    { path: '', loadChildren: './content-container/container.module#ContainerModule' }
  ]}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(firstRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FirstRoutes {}
```

Comment: This seems to be the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52143306/unable-to-get-the-path-nor-url-from-angular-router/52143966#52143966

Comment: Check the demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgahsx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 39):

Instead of trying to use `Router` (which is not ready to give you final route at this moment of navigation lifecycle), you can use `Location` service (https://angular.io/api/common/Location) and its method `path`, which will give you the url without base href. On the contrary, `window.location.pathname` is not aware of your angular toys and will give you path including base href.

```js
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private location: Location) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.location.path());
  }

}
```

Comment: its return the same with the "/" @carecki

Comment: It works perfectly for me in angular 7, Alternatively we can use JS core function        console.log(window.location.href, this.router)

Comment: This is the solution to use if you don't want to wait (can be used in constructor too).

Comment: This worked great on Angular 9.  Thanks for submitting!

Answer (score 14):

I have the same issue.  The router.url returns a slash because when ngOnInit runs on the main app component, the route is the root. I got the correct value for the url by doing this.

```
  this.router.events
  .pipe(
    filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  )
  .subscribe( (navEnd:NavigationEnd) => {
    console.log(navEnd.urlAfterRedirects);
  });
```

Hope that helps.  This did not work with Angular Universal however... still trying to figure that out.

Comment: This is a great answer and should be part of accepted answer.

Comment: To get better typechecking in TypeScript, make the filter operator's predicate into a type guard: `filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd)`

Answer (score 1):

> Type 1.We can also use window.location.pathname

```
Type 2.constructor(router: Router) { 

      router.events.subscribe((url:any) => console.log(url));

      console.log(router.url);  // to print only path eg:"/login"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the url whenever you click on a new link/page you should use this:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((routerData) => {
      if(routerData instanceof ResolveEnd){ 
         if(routerData.url === 'your url'){
           //Do something
         }
    } 
})
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the only solution that worked for me on Angular 11.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is 4 years old me and others will find it when looking for this issue. I had this problem while checking urls in the AuthGuard CanActivate interfaced class. For me the answers did not work, since at the point the guard is checking the URL, it is not available in Location nor in router.url. This worked for me:

```
const finalUrl = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.finalUrl;   
const isLoginPage = finalUrl?.root.children['primary'].segments[0]?.path === 'login';
```

this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.finalUrl returns an UrlTree that might seem a bit complicated to use, my example above only works since "login" will always be my first segment. For a better understanding you should take a look at this example usage from the documentation:

```
@Component({templateUrl:'template.html'})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(router: Router) {
    const tree: UrlTree =
      router.parseUrl('/team/33/(user/victor//support:help)?debug=true#fragment');
    const f = tree.fragment; // return 'fragment'
    const q = tree.queryParams; // returns {debug: 'true'}
    const g: UrlSegmentGroup = tree.root.children[PRIMARY_OUTLET];
    const s: UrlSegment[] = g.segments; // returns 2 segments 'team' and '33'
    g.children[PRIMARY_OUTLET].segments; // returns 2 segments 'user' and 'victor'
    g.children['support'].segments; // return 1 segment 'help'
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/api/router/UrlTree#usage-notes

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.url=this.routers.url; 
}, 100);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).