# Unable to get the path nor url from angular router

Tags: javascript, angular, url, path, angular-router

I am unable to get the URL nor the path from ActivatedRoute nor Router imports. It outputs a blank for path "" and '/' for URL. I remember using a working version. The only thing that captures the right route the Router.events. I am also unable to subscribe to the URL in the ActivatedRoute. Here is the code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, UrlSegment, NavigationStart, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'api-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  routePath: string = '';

  constructor(
    private _r: Router,
    private _ar: ActivatedRoute) {
    this._r.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
      if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
          // '/teams' output with route http://localhost:4200/teams
        console.log(event.url);
      }
      // NavigationStart // NavigationEnd // NavigationCancel // NavigationError // RoutesRecognized
    });

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this._ar.pathFromRoot.toString()); // Blank output with route http://localhost:4200/teams
    console.log(this._ar.routeConfig.path.toString());  // Blank output with route http://localhost:4200/teams
    console.log(this._ar.snapshot.url);  // Blank output with route http://localhost:4200/teams
    this._ar.url.subscribe((urlsegment: UrlSegment[]) =>{
      console.log(urlsegment) // Unable to subscribe with route change to /teams
    })
  }

}
```

Anything I am missing here? I have seen this [Angular router url returns slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320416/angular-router-url-returns-slash)

My routes:

```
const APPMainRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'teams', component: CollaborateComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
];
```

My ng versions:

Angular CLI: 6.1.4
Node: 10.7.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

### Package                           Version

@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.4
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.4
@angular/cdk                      6.4.6
@angular/material                 6.4.6
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.4
@schematics/angular               0.7.4
@schematics/update                0.7.4
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2

Comment: As i can see, You have not use DashboardComponent inside your Routes. and remove slash from "redirectTo: '/login'"

Comment: It did not help. It might not help as well. My issue is with `/teams` route not getting captured as `/` or path as `""` I would have worried if it was only with `/login`

Comment: Seems it works only with events capture withing constructor - if you noticed

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mv9wy7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts see this demo.. here i am able to get url using Router

Comment: Aniket, Check the result in app.component in this demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-taiifx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Aniket, the problem is I am also not able to subscribe the url change from app.component

Answer (score 1):

You can get url info like this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this._r.url);
  }
```

And if you need to get queryParams in the url
You can get :

```
this._r.snapshot.queryParamMap
```

Comment: Sorry didnt work - neither. Getting a '/' and map is empty

Comment: @Gary please check your url setting in Routes module.  if you access http://localhost/test , then this._r.url have to return /test.

Comment: @what is url for DashboardComponent ??

Comment: Good catch - Its the sidebar. and is the parent dom for router-outlet. The route components can catch the url.

Comment: Can you check the link here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-taiifx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @Gary check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9mute?file=src/app/login/login.component.ts If you need to get url /login /team , then you should define LoginComponent or TeamComponent. And if you want to get the url link in the parent component, you have to use another way...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179294/discussion-between-gary-and-jihoon-kwon).

Answer (score 1):

You can check instanceof **NavigationStart** and **NavigationEnd**

here's is the example

in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        console.log('start => ',event.url);
      }
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log('end => ',event.url);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abgvcf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)  demo

Answer (score 1):

The component where I was trying to access the url or the path was the host/parent/parallel component to the  component tree. All the above failures allowed capture of right path `inside` the route components but not the parent/host/paralleltree component. Only Router.events work there. Surprisingly I was unable to capture and make work the ActivatedRoute.url.subscribe as well inside the parent/host.

```
<app-cmp>
Router and ActivatedRoute does not Work here. Only Router.events Work here
<router-outlet>
<team-cmp>Router and ActivatedRoute Works here</team-cmp>
</router-outlet>
<sidebar-cmp>
Router and ActivatedRoute does not Work here. Only Router.events Work here
<sidebar-cmp>
</app-cmp>
```

This works in host/parent/parallel tree -  or :

```
// inject in constructor
constructor( private _router: Router) {

// Call below anywhere within Init or Constructor etc
this._router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
      if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        console.log(event.url); // WORKS
      }
      // NavigationStart // NavigationEnd // NavigationCancel // NavigationError // RoutesRecognized
    });

}
```

Comment: thx a lot ! it helped me get the URL the user typed in his browser on boostrapped app component on init (I was trying to get the 'landing page' the user intended to go before anything is actually rendered)

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails you can use `location.pathname` which is global