# Angular : how to get url on page load and check if contain text

Tags: angular, typescript

I was able to get the `authkey` value using route `paramMap`, but how do we get the url. For example, I want to check if URL contains `resetpassword` text as you can see on the link below. How do we do that in Angular?

How do we get URL or if URL contains certain text on page load? Check if URL contains "resetpassword" text.

##### Code

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap) => {
    console.log("paramMap" , paramMap)
    this.code = paramMap.get('authkey');
    if (this.code) {
      this.code = paramMap.get('authkey').replace('authkey:', '');
      this.getEmail(this.code);
    }
  });
}
```

##### Example URL

```
http://localhost:4200/#/login/resetpassword/authkey:6762b362-1a62-4077-8ae4-78b381REX7JEXE4a8f30
```

[image: URL in address bar]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current url in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184969/get-current-url-in-angular)

Comment: No , cause I also wanted to check if url contains specific string

Comment: cant really find a solution

Comment: Ok. 2 approaches: You can get the url as described in the other answer, and then google for "js check if string contains substring" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript. Or you google directly "js check if url contains text" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597050/how-to-check-if-the-url-contains-a-given-string

Comment: let subscring ="resetpassword"
    console.log("thisss" ,this.router.url.includes(subscring))

Comment: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'Observable<UrlSegment[]>'.ts(2339)
any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include is a function that can use to find a string value in a string

```
if(this.router.url.includes('resetpassword')){
  //Implement code here if exists 
}else{
 //Implement code here if not exists 
}
```