# In Angular is there a way to get text from the URL and set it as a variable?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have dropdown filters that filter some data, I'd like to be able to set one of these dropdowns with a value from the URL. Is this possible?

Comment: Checkout the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) API.

Comment: `window.location.href` gives you the current URL. If you want url parameters you can use the `ActivatedRoute` service to do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check this: [How to retrieve the url in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45185477/8013381)

Than you can for sure use the url to compose the options in the dropdown based on your custom logics.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing, thank you for the link.