# Angular separate Sidebar

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-services, angular-components

I'm using angular 4 in my project where I'm having 3 different sidebars (i.e with different content). I've enclosed an image below. In that, I want the component separation to be like. HomeScreen with no Sidebar. And Screen 1 with sidebar 1, Screen 2 With sidebar 2, Similarly sidebar 3 on the third screen. Which will be the efficient method to separate those sidebar components

[image]

Comment: it seems like you have sidebar but with different content not separate sidebar for mentioned screen..

Comment: I'm really asking for suggestions because, I don't really like to create more components for side bar alone like sidebar1, 2 and 3. Since most of the UI Is same I want to use that as common layout and changing the contents based on the cliked links from the sidebar

Comment: Then you can hide this sidebar when route is 'home' page

Comment: By using a seperate service for sidebar?

Comment: Create separate component and template for sidebar and load it to your pages where you actually require

Answer (score 0):

Create parent component for those pages which have sidebar or you can hide this sidebar based on the route. like you can hide sidebar when route is home.

Comment: any reference link would help

Comment: May it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route

Answer (score 0):

Got Exactly What I'm Looking for , [Angular Dynamic Sidebar](https://netbasal.com/implementing-dynamic-views-in-angular-20ae7c62fec3)