# Angular2 View Initial Route URL

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to get the initial route's url(the route that happens when you reload the page).

I want to apply a css style to an element based on it.

So far I injected ActivatedRoute console logged it like so:

```
  constructor(private router: Router, private actRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
     console.log(actRoute);
```

Chrome then shows an ActivatedRoute object containing a _routerState property which has a snapshot with the url that I want.

The problem is that when I do: `console.log(actRoute._routerState);` I get an error because the router state property doesn't exist.

Am I missing something here? Because just writing `actRoute.url` or `actRoute.snapshot.url` just gives an empty path.

Thanks.

My imports:
`import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: did you try  console.log(this.router.url);?

Comment: also did you import Router?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes I have router imported and I tried using `this` but I get the same output.

Comment: This might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41779066/5695162)

Comment: I just set a redirect url on the first load after getting the current route, and my auth guard redirects to that if the user is logged in. Don't use activated route at all.

Comment: @RomanKoval check my answer.

Comment: @Vikas I tried all of those and some throw errors in VSCode and other just give blanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to view only the first, initial, route.

In my `app.component.ts` I created a local variable `event` and then set it equal to the `this.router.events.subscribe` function.

After I was done with the router I just called `this.even.this.event.unsubscribe()`.

Here's my code:

```
event;

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.event = this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(e);

        // Doing stuff with the router

        this.event.unsubscribe();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And my imports:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Router` and following will give you the complete path:

```
this.router.routerState.snapshot.url
```

Comment: All I get is a blank in console with this.