# how we can get the current page from app.component in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic4

i am trying to get current page instance in app.component in ionic 4.

in ionic 3 i can do it like this

**this.nav.getActive().instance**

Comment: Which Component you are using for Navigation in ionic 4 ? @ionic/angulra ?

Comment: Are you using Angular router? https://www.joshmorony.com/using-angular-routing-with-ionic-4/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route

Comment: in app component i want to execute some method of the acive page. first i will check if the method is present, then i execute it

Comment: I am using like this this.navCtrl.navigateForward('url')

Answer (score 23):

You can access the url from the Router.

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class YourPage implements OnInit {
   constructor(private router: Router) {}

   ngOnInit() {
        console.log('this.router.url', this.router.url);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very helpful !

Comment: Simple and effective!

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a similar situation. In a multi-page application, I need the *instance* of the current class component.

Basically, I have a modal that can open on each page and ask the user if she wants to reload data or not. When the user chooses *yes*, I want to reach the current page instance and call a *reload* method on it.

I ended up with this dirty trick. I'm not an Angular/JS/Ionic expert, so probably there are better and cleaner ways to do this. Use this at your own risk, in my situation *it seems to work*, although not perfectly (see later).

## The idea

My idea is simple: when a new page component class is instantiated (constructor called), I bind it to the url used to navigate to it .

Class instantiation happens before navigation ends, so when navigation end event occurs, I use the final url to get back the instance.

## Code

### Invoking code from current page

In my `app.component.ts`, I put the event handler with the call to the page component methods:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private navEnd: Observable<NavigationEnd>;

  constructor(
    // ... other dependencies
    private router: Router,
    private routeMap: RouteMap // this is my class, see later
  ) {

    this.navEnd = router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ) as Observable<NavigationEnd>;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navEnd.subscribe(evt => {
      let instance = this.routeMap.getObject(evt.urlAfterRedirects);
      if (instance != null) {
        instance.doStuff();
        // ... or save instance elsewhere, like
        //   this.aService.setCurrentPage(instance);
        // or anything you need
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In the `subscribe` call, I use `evt.urlAfterRedirects` instead of `evt.url` to handle the case when the empty path redirects to the first page, like this (in `app-routing.module.ts`):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'categories', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'page1', loadChildren: './pages/page1/page1.module#Page1PageModule' },
  // ...
];
```

If you have a similar configuration, when you navigate `/` and the `NavigationEnd` event occurs, `evt.url` is `/` and `evt.urlAfterRedirects` is `/home`.

When you navigate to `/page1` and then *go back* to home page using the back button, when `NavigationEnd` occurs, both `evt.url` and `evt.urlAfterRedirects` are `/home`.

To be sure that in both cases I get the instance, I need to user `urlAfterRedirects`.

### Tracking current page

In my pages, I change the constructors like this:

```
export HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private routeMap: RouteMap // again my code
  ) {
    routeMap.registerObject(router.getCurrentNavigation().finalUrl.toString(), this);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Basically, when the constructor is called, I know the instance of the component class, so I bind it to the current url.

This code is quite rough, probably it's better to factorize it out, making a superclass, a decorator, a mixin, so that you don't have to duplicate the code on each page. Being not a Javascript or Angular expert, here I'm a bit lost. I would go with a superclass (because I just know them), but probably it's better something else.

### The `RouteMap` code

This is where tracking happens. It is a little service you can put where you like.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteMap {
  private map: {
    path: string,
    object: object
  }[] = [];

  getObject(path: string) {
    let item = this.map.find(function (item) {
      return item.path == path;
    });

    return item ? item.object : null;
  }

  registerObject(path: string, object: object) {
    let item = this.map.find(function (item) {
      return item.path == path;
    });

    if (item) {
      item.object = object;
    } else {
      this.map.push({
        path: path,
        object: object
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The `registerObject()` first check if the given `path` has already been mapped to an object. If that is the case, it just update the object, so that you don't have duplicated paths. Otherwise, it adds a new entry in the map.

The `getObject()` searches the map for the give `path` and gives the registered object if the path exists. Otherwise it gives `null`.

## Issues

### Bad behavior with *first* tab in tabbed view

In my case, I have a sequence of pages `Home -> Page1 -> ... -> PageN -> TabbedPage` where the last is a page that has 3 tabs.

`TabbedPage` has this routing definition:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabbedPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [{
          path: '',
          loadChildren: './tab1/tab1.module#Tab1Module'
        }]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [{
          path: '',
          loadChildren: './tab2/tab2.module#Tab2Module'
        }]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [{
          path: '',
          loadChildren: './tab3/tab3.module#Tab3Module'
        }]
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

so when I navigate to `/tabbedpage`, it automatically opens the `/tabbedpage/tab1` tab.

However, I noticed that if I try to track the `Tab1` instance with

```
export class Tab1 implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private routeMap: RouteMap
  ) {
    routeMap.registerObject(router.getCurrentNavigation().finalUrl.toString(), this);
  }

}
```

it does not work: `getCurrentNavigation()` gives `null`. I logged the navigation events and I've noticed that *no navigation occurs* from `TabbedPage` to `Tab1`. `Tab1` is just instantiated.

So I have this sequence of events:

- navigation starts to `/tabbedpage`
- (internal) redirect from `/tabbedpage` to `/tabbedpage/tab1` found
- `TabbedPage` is created and bound to `/tabbedpage/tab1`
- navigation ends from `/tabbedpage` to `/tabbedpage/tab1`
- `Tab1` is created

After that, if I navigate the other tabs, the instances of `Tab2` and `Tab3` are correctly bound to `/tabbedpage/tab2` and `/tabbedpage/tab3`. If I navigate back to `Tab1`, I get the instance of `TabbedPage`.

---

At the moment I have not found other particular issues, but the code is enough for my case.

Let see if it is useful to you too.

Bye

Answer (score 3):

I did this one and it works for me:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {  
   console.log(this.router['routerState'].snapshot.url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u can track the current page using the routeroutlet

```
<router-outlet (activate)="componentName = $event"></router-outlet>
```

check documentation for more info 
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Answer (score 1):

in my case I used an observable to solve this situation

here's my url Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrentPageService {
  private $urlParts:BehaviorSubject<any>;
  private url;
  constructor(private router:Router) { 
    this.$urlParts = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  }
  get urlParts(){
    return this.$urlParts.asObservable();
  }
  setUrl(){
    this.url=this.router.url;
    let parts = this.url.split('/');
    return this.$urlParts.next(parts);
  }
}
```

and any page that I'm interested in getting its currently active state in my app component i trigger this observable

```
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private currentPage:CurrentPageService) {

  }
ionViewDidEnter(){
  this.currentPage.setUrl();
}
```

and finally in my appcomponent

```
export class AppComponent {
urlParts;
constructor(private currentpage:CurrentPageService){
      this.currentPage.urlParts.subscribe(url=>this.urlParts=url);
    });
}
foo(){
        if (!this.urlParts.includes('home')) {
          //do something
        }
}

}
```

Answer (score -3):

In Ionic 4 use below code to get current page name using `NavController`

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.navCtrl.router.routerState.snapshot.url)
}
```

Hope this will helps!

Comment: I want to get instance not name of the current page componen. so that i can execute any method of the current page from app.component

Comment: navCtrl doesn't have method or variable as `router`