# Getting current URL using InAppBrowser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm trying to get the current `URL` using the `InAppBrowser Cordova plugin`, `e.url` is returning the first loaded `URL` only (`this.weburl`).

Am I doing something wrong? or is there an alternative way to approach the same goal?

```
       this.browser = this.iab.create(this.weburl, '_blank');
       this.browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(
        (e: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
          alert(e.url);
        }
```

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54746197/how-we-can-get-the-current-page-from-app-component-in-ionic-4

Comment: I don't think that routes will work, because the web page is handled using the plugin InAppBrowser

Comment: Have you tried using `Routes`?

Comment: Not really, I'm just using NavController Push/Pop for navigation in the moment