# How to use same Login page for different user in Angular 6

Tags: authentication, routes, angular6

I have two different user.
One is Admin.Other one is User.I have to reuse the same LoginComponent for both User and Admin.
If i will hit URL http://localhost:4200/user , then login page will come **where forgot password link will be there**.
But i will hit URL http://localhost:4200/admin , then same login page will come **where forgot password link will not be there**.

In Routes i have given path like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
];
```

Can anyone please help me how can i have same login page with different content based on the URL hit.

Comment: One option could be [getting the current route](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34597835/4636715) (as one is `admin` other is `user`) in the component and make that *Forgot Password* mount depending on that (with [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) or such)

Comment: Yes, Working :). Thank you @vahdet