# How to get all segments of route in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

consider my url is like

`#/desktop/admin/reconciliationconfig/nav/ledger/GMO-DDA-21819971/detail`,

My question is how can I get all segments of the route in angular?

My expected result is

`['desktop','admin','reconciliationconfig','nav','ledger','GMO-DDA-21819971','detail']`

Note `GMO-DDA-21819971` is a route param and will be changed dynamically

Comment: Use any method mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route) to get the URL and then parse it into an array based off the forward slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the url from the `router` object, you can simply use the `split` function in the string

```
this.router.url.split('/');
```