# Angular get matched url path in Guard

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-guards, angular-routerlink

my routing is

```
{
path:'contacts/:id',
component: contactDetail
}
```

in

```
canActivateChild( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot) { 
  console.log(state.url); 
}
```

state.url return `/contacts/1` what I need is matched url `/contact/:id` is there any possibilities to get matched url?

Comment: Try Among the options provided here if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route

Answer (score 5):

You'll have it in `route.routeConfig.path`:

```
canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) { 
  console.log(route.routeConfig.path);
}
```

Thanks @Thirumalai murugan

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan you're right, this is working for `canActivate` and not for `canActivateChild`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: `route.routeConfig.path` is returning the result

Comment: You're correct. it does. there are both pointing to the same place. but this path is match better. I'll update my answer. cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            // authorised so return true
            return true;
        }
        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/account']);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Did you answer this question or another?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActivatedRoute`

```
import { ActivatedRoute} from @angular/router';
 constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(res => {
    if(res.id) { //your code }
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time, sorry to say this, Its angular project not a ionic one and more over my basic need is to get matched url `/contact/:id` in guard

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan sorry, please see updated answer

Comment: Please look into the question, I need matched url in guard, the work around is the final step that too I need it in guard not in the component, sorry, for your convenience I have deleted that work around points too.

Answer (score 0):

Using ActivatedRouteSnapshot you can get the route with its parameters. Check if below code helps.

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    console.log(next['routeConfig']['path']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next statement:

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
 ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean |     
UrlTree {
console.log(next.queryParams);
console.log(next.params);

return true;
```

}