# How to get Activatedroute in angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, angular-activatedroute

I want to get the route when the URL changes

```
https://localhost:3200
```

to

```
https://localhotst:3200/login
```

how can i get login when there is change in route
I tried ActivateRoute but the code i made is not working

Here is what I've tried :

```
route.params.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy)
).subscribe(params => {
  if (this.currentDialog) {
    this.currentDialog.close();
  }
  this.currentDialog = matDialog.open(DialogComponent, {
    data: { tabvalue, param.id}
  }); //this is the code i took from a web site but i don't know how to apply it
});
```

In param.id  here id is a variable but i don't want to use it. I just want path: 'login', component: NavbarComponent } someting like this path

Comment: You need a code which intercept the router everytime it change ?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I know that but i am unable to write that code

Comment: route.params.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy)).subscribe(params => {
      if (this.currentDialog) {
        this.currentDialog.close();
    }this.currentDialog = matDialog.open(DialogComponent, {
        data: {tabvalue, param.id},
    })  //this is the code i took from a web site but i don't know how to apply it

Comment: have you declared **ActivatedRoute** in your component constructor?

Comment: yes, but the above code is wrong

Comment: Does this answer help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38536754/6444705. You will need to use Router instead of ActivatedRoute

Comment: Thanks This is perfectly working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to route change via [route event](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent).

To get changes globally, you can set the subscription in in your app.component.ts for example.

Get only the NavigationEnd event, and then retrieve the desired url.

```js
    class MyClass implements OnInit {
    
        constructor(private router: Router) {}
    
        ngOnInit() {
            this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent) => {
                if(routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                    // Get your url
                    console.log(routerEvent.url);
                }
            });
        }}
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code.

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.forEach((params: Params) => {
      console.log(params['givenKey']);

      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: but I am not using any key 
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: NavbarComponent },//this is the main router opens when init shown by router-outlet
  { path: 'login', component: NavbarComponent },
  { path: 'signin', component: NavbarComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];

Comment: this is my route config

Comment: what do you want using activated route?

Comment: Actually I am using a dialog which is triggered by a button (name login) but when i add url manually Dialog doesn't opens