# Get next route URL in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular (version >= 2), how to get the next route (URL) from router's navigation events?
For example, in the code below, how do I know the next route that Angular will navigate into?

```
    router.events.subscribe(routerEvent => {
      // How to get next route URL here ?
    })
```

`router` has type Router (imported from '@angular/router')

Comment: `this.activatedRoute.firstChild` will give you the first next of url then go further and its .firstChild will give the next part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597835/how-to-get-current-route)

Comment: @Kinglish No, the link is about getting current route, not the next route. For example, when routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart, I logged this.router.url but it prints the current route.

Comment: I think the only solution to detect the destination is available by setting a guard for route changes, seems you can not detect destination by router events.