# How do I hide the 'Previous' button on the first page in Angular 15?

Tags: angular, typescript, conditional-statements, rendering

I have a 'form' that the user selects an option and the app takes them to the next page where they need to select again an option. Each list of options is a different component. I also have a header component which is static and is displayed on all pages. I would like to hide the `Previous` button on the first page, how can I do that?

I can use `ngIf` directive for conditional rendering but how can I know on which page I am now? And how do I translate that into Angular + Typescript code?

Thank you

Comment: there has been a post on how to get current route in Angular 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/34597835/19433398

Answer (score 0):

You create a container component that renders the other components. Then for the component that you want to hide previous button on, you can pass in an `@Input()` variable `hidePrevious`. Your container component will know if this component should hide previous or not.