# Angular 2 Dynamic Breadcrumbs

Tags: angular, router, breadcrumbs

I need some help with breadcrumbs

Here example routes config

```js
Routes = [  
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},  
    {path: 'home', ..., data: { breadcrumb: 'Home'}},  
    {path: 'about', ..., data: { breadcrumb: 'About'}},  
    {path: 'github', ..., data: { breadcrumb: 'GitHub'},
    {
       path: 'category/:id',
       component: CategoryComponent
    },  
]
```

In bread crumbs component i try to use this to extract breadcrumbs data from `ActivatedRoute`

```js
ngOnInit() {
   // subscribe to the NavigationEnd event
   this.router.events.filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(() => {

      // set breadcrumbs
      const root: ActivatedRoute = this.activatedRoute.root;
      this.breadcrumbs = this.getBreadcrumbs(root);
   });
 }
```

After that i render comonentns template

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
   <li><a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active"><i class="fa fa-home position-left"></i> Главная</a></li>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs">
   <li routerLinkActive="active">
      <a [routerLink]="[breadcrumb.url, breadcrumb.params]"> {{ breadcrumb.label }}</a>
   </li>
   </ng-container>
</ul>
```

All fine but i dont know how i can pass data value from another component for `category/:id` route for make in human readable like "Mobile Phones"

Comment: I guess you are looking to pass data between components and this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766767/2708210

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi @Grey2k possible to share `getBreadcrumbs()` function please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope it's not too late to answer this question :D, so here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ppnw8o95pq) example with two breadcrumb implementations, that uses the `router` `data` option to pass and collect data for the breadcrumb.

### Code explanation:

Look at the comments inside the breadcrumb component.

#### Here is the breacrumb component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  Router,
  Event,
  ActivationStart,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  ActivationEnd,
  NavigationEnd,
  NavigationStart
} from "@angular/router";
import { filter, map, buffer, pluck } from "rxjs/operators";

/**
 * Check if an angular router 'Event' is instance of 'NavigationEnd' event
 */
const isNavigationEnd = (ev: Event) => ev instanceof NavigationEnd;
/**
 * Check if an angular router 'Event' is instance of 'NavigationEnd' event
 */
const isActivationEnd = (ev: Event) => ev instanceof ActivationEnd;

@Component({
  selector: "app-breadcrumb",
  templateUrl: "./breadcrumb.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./breadcrumb.component.scss"]
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {
  bcLoadedData;
  bcForDisplay;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    /**
     * navigationEnd$ is trigered once per completed routing event, in other words
     * once per loading a component that is in the end of the current route
     */
    const navigationEnd$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter(isNavigationEnd));

    /**
     * Here we subscribe to all navigation events, in order to update
     * our route "data", which we will use for the breadcrumb visualization.
     *
     * Than we filter the events emitted from the `router` in such way, that we are only
     * taking action upon a completed router event (in other words we are subscribing only for `ActivationEnd`
     * events)
     *
     * We use pluck to get only the requried bredcrumb data
     *
     * The buffer operator accumulates all `data` coming from the router and emmits the accumulated data once
     * when a `NavigationEnd` event passes troufh `navigationEnd$`
     *
     * The `map` in the end is used to reverse the collected data, in order to convert it to more logical
     * sequence. Without the revers first we will get the data for the current route, after that for it's parent
     * and so on (that is how the ng router works).
     */
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(isActivationEnd),
        pluck("snapshot"),
        pluck("data"),
        buffer(navigationEnd$),
        map((bcData: any[]) => bcData.reverse())
      )
      .subscribe(x => {
        this.bcLoadedData = x;
      });
  }
}
```

```css
.breadcrumb {
    display: flex;

    &.simple {
        border: 2px solid blueviolet;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .breadcrumb-separator {
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb simple">
    <div *ngFor="let bcElement of bcLoadedData; let last = last">
        {{bcElement.bc}}
        <span class="breadcrumb-separator"
              *ngIf="!last">></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Here is the structure of the routes

```js
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: MockComponentComponent, data: { bc: 'Looking outside' } },
 {
  path: 'home', component: MockComponentComponent,
  data: { bc: 'I see a home' },
  children: [
   {
    path: 'primaryHouse', component: MockComponentComponent,
    data: { bc: 'I\'m going inside the home' },
    children: [
     {
      path: 'kitchen', component: MockComponentComponent,
      data: { bc: 'look inside the kitchen' }
     },
     {
      path: 'bedroom', component: MockComponentComponent,
      data: { bc: 'look inside the bedroom' }
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    path: 'guestHouse', component: MockComponentComponent,
    data: { bc: 'I\'m going in the back yard' }
   }
  ]
 }
];
```

Comment: What about page refresh? This triggers only when navigation happens, not if we are already on a route and page is refreshed.

Comment: The aggregation of `data` works with page refreshes, so im not sure to what are you reffering. 
If you are reffering the part of the example that uses dynamicly aggregated data inside the breadcrumbs (e.g. the breakIns from the example) it's normal for them to be removed, as they are stored in memory and disappear on refresh. You can preserve does additional elements by adding them to you query parameters for example (and after that you can parse the query parameters and get your past breadcrumbs).

Comment: My bad. Instead of app/main module I did this in one of the child module's sub component. So it didn't listen to initial page load. It only listen to router after that component's init. 

I guess this is a lesson that do this in main module.

Comment: @ХристиянХристов do you have stackblitz for this buddy?

Comment: @Mr.Learner https://codesandbox.io/s/ppnw8o95pq i guess this should help you

Comment: @ХристиянХристов thanks for your super quick response buddy. let me understand your implementation. Thanks alot for your effort

Answer (score 1):

Any breadcrumb solution has to handle

1. declarative approach of defining breadcrumbs in routing
2. Dynamic asynchronous way to update any route by a different label
3. way to skip specific routes from displaying in breadcrumbs

I have created a library to handle all these called **xng-breadcrumbs** - https://github.com/udayvunnam/xng-breadcrumb

feel free to check, An Angular app developed showing the breadcrumbs usage - https://xng-breadcrumb.netlify.com

Comment: I get into some component, say Dashboard in above link. It shows page not found. can you tell me why it is not working on refresh?

Comment: The issue is with configuring netlify. I will fix the demo app

Comment: you can check the documentation at https://udayvunnam.github.io/xng-breadcrumb/#/