# sharing data using service attribut in angular 2 between component

Tags: angular, service, share

i have the same problem of this issue :

[Share data between components using a service in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567674/share-data-between-components-using-a-service-in-angular2)

but it won't work because i think injecting service into two components mean that there is two instance ot the service class . so trying to modify the data from component in the service and see the change in the other component still not working . what is the solution so ?

NB :

i have try the solutions in the comments but still not working  ...

this is my service  :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

   counter: number = 0 ;
  constructor() {
    console.log('instanciate Test Service' + this.counter ) ;
    this.counter ++ ;

  }

   setCounter(counter: number){
    this.counter =counter ;
    console.log('new value of counter is ' + this.counter );
  }


}
```

the first component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'rb-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit , OnChanges ,DoCheck{
  bindingdata = 'test' ;
  data: number;


  constructor(public  _ts: TestService) {

  }
   ngOnChanges(){
    this.data=this._ts.counter ;
    console.log('is changing');
   }
   ngDoCheck(){
     this.data=this._ts.counter ;

     console.log('is doing check');

   }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this._ts.counter;
        }
}
```

template of the first component :

```
{{data}}
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bindingdata" />
```

the second component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'rb-other-test',
  templateUrl: './other-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./other-test.component.css']
})
export class OtherTestComponent implements OnInit ,OnDestroy{
  data: number;
  constructor(public _ts: TestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.data= this._ts.counter;
  }

  public  change(){
    this._ts.setCounter(7878);
    this.data = this._ts.counter;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }

}
```

the template of second component :

```
<input type="submit" value="change" (click)="change()">

{{data}}
```

result :

[image]

Comment: Injecting a service more than once does not create multiple instances. There will only be two instances if you *provided* it twice (the `providers: [...]` line). Provide the service in a module that both components live within instead.

Comment: should i declare the variable static in the service ?

Comment: Nope, that more or less defeats the whole point of services. Try adding a console.log to the service's constructor to see if it's really being constructed twice.

Comment: no , it instanciate one time

Comment: You'll have to post some code. The problem could be anything. It could be a change detection issue, for example.

Comment: ok , one moment

Comment: you can take a look now  ...

Comment: I put your code in a plunkr and it seems to work? http://plnkr.co/edit/jOnOTKi5wWgRi1rNGJaM

Comment: i have add a picture trying to see if it's work  or not , you can see that is not working

Comment: You're running the app twice in separate windows?

Comment: Yes I do.  Each component in a windows

Comment: did i make another mistake ?

Comment: Each window has its own separate instance of the whole app. This won't work unless you use Websockets or something...

Comment: yes , you are right . i  resolved  it , thank you