# Angular2 : get hold of an element in template of a sibling component from a component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

recently started Angular2, came across the below scenario

where need to access the element from a sibling component, but not from Parent Cmp. Thanks for looking at it

***Example:***

- Let's say we have component A and component B which are on same
  level.
- Need the iframe element in templateA in ComponentB to Hide or
  delete the element.

**index.html**

```
<component-A> </component-A>
<component-B> </component-B>
```

**ComponentA.html**

```
<div>
  <iframe id="someIframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

**ComponentB.html**

```
<div>
   <form id="someForm"></form>
</div>
```

**@component**

```
({
 selector:'component-A',
 templateUrl:'/componentA.html'

})

constructor() {

}
```

**@component**

```
({
 selector:'component-B',
 templateUrl:'/componentB.html'

})

constructor() {
 //need to get hold of the iframe element to hide that.
}
```

Comment: yes you can do it using Input and output function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ViewChild` to get ahold of the sibling component. So your Component B class should look something like this;

```
import {Component,ViewChild,AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ComponentA}         from './componentA';

@Component({
    selector: 'component-B',
    templateUrl: '/componentB.html'
})
export class ComponentB implements AfterViewInit{
    @ViewChild(ComponentA) 
    child:ComponentA; //say get the first instance of ComponentA

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.child); //access the child here
    }
}
```

Read more about @ViewChild [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can share data between siblings:

- **using a shared service**: I had asked a similar question a few months back. Take a look here:
  [share data using service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567674/share-data-between-components-using-a-service-in-angular2)
- **Communicating using parent**: You could create a parent component to these siblings and then sibling can communicate using this parent component. So your data transfer would happen as **sibling1 -> parent -> sibling2**. More details here: [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction)

Answer (score -1):

I would certainly not want to access the element directly from component B, you'll want to leave them decoupled.

2 possible ways of solving this is:

- Using a service which contains a toggle to hide or show the iframe.
- Or you could use an event mechanism where you fire an event from
  component B which component A listens to and it toggles the iframe
  element accordingly.