# shared information between components through service not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im having some trouble figuring this out, basically I have a `headerTitleService` which I want to be able to dynamically set the title in my `header` component but for some reason when I set the title nothing shows up? Im not getting any errors so I can seem to figure out what the problem is..

**headerTitle.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderTitleService {
  title = new BehaviorSubject('');

  constructor() { }

  setTitle(title: string) {
    this.title.next(title);
  }
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderTitleService } from '../../../services/headerTitle.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  providers: [HeaderTitleService]
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;

  constructor(
    private headerTitleService: HeaderTitleService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headerTitleService.title.subscribe(updatedTitle => {
      this.title = updatedTitle;
    });
  }

}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderTitleService } from '../../services/headerTitle.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  providers: [HeaderTitleService]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private headerTitleService: HeaderTitleService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.headerTitleService.setTitle('hello');
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between components using a service in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567674/share-data-between-components-using-a-service-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `providers: [HeaderTitleService]` in each component means that they will be given one `HeaderTitleService` each, rather than one between them.

To fix this remove `providers: [HeaderTitleService]` from your components, and place it in your module definition instead:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [HeaderTitleService]
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Move **HeaderTitleService** in providers of your module. With your implementation you receive new instance of the **HeaderTitleService** in each component.

Hope this helps.