# how to get grid data from ag-grid angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I created a component and use ag-grid at it. Assuming I have package this component and do not want to change it.
How to get grid data in parent component?
I tried using @ViewChild but the data is received as a async Returns its undefined value.
Is there a way to access the table model and get the data? This data may change as the page changes and I should understand.

Thank you that help me.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: You can create services to get data like this [angular services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567674/share-data-between-components-using-a-service-in-angular2)

Comment: Data should be stored in separate service. This service should feed ag-grid and other components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ViewChild

```
  @ViewChild(YourGridComponent) gridComponent: YourGridComponent;
```

And access your component **this** object

Comment: Many thanks, But how do I access table information?